# ¿Cuál es la convención para escribir variables en Java?

Tags: java

Para el caso de nombres de variables con una sola palabra lo normal es escribirlas de la siguiente forma:

```
int entero;
double doble;
String cadena;
```

Pero para el caso de variables que usan dos palabras ¿cómo se deben escribir?, yo sólo he usado dos formas:

- Opción 1:

  `int numero_entero;`

  `double numero_doble;`
- Opción 2:

  `int numeroEntero;`

  `double numeroDoble;`

También he notado que algunas variables que tienen las bibliotecas de Java están escritas en mayúsculas y separadas por   **_**:

```
Foo.ANCHURA_MAXIMA;
Foo.ANCHURA_MINIMA;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Las convenciones de nombre hacen que los programas sean más comprensibles al hacerlos más fáciles de leer. También pueden proporcionar información sobre la función del identificador, por ejemplo, si es una constante, un paquete o una clase, lo que puede ser útil para comprender el código.

La [documentación de Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) indica en resumen su convención de nombres:

---

#### `Paquetes`

El prefijo de un nombre de paquete único se escribe siempre en letras ASCII en **minúsculas** y debería ser uno de los nombres de dominio de nivel superior, actualmente com, edu, gov, mil, net, org o uno de los códigos de dos letras en inglés identificando países como se especifica en la [Norma ISO 3166, 1981](https://www.iso.org/iso-3166-country-codes.html).

Los componentes subsiguientes del nombre del paquete varían de acuerdo con las convenciones de nomenclatura internas de una organización. Tales convenciones podrían especificar que ciertos componentes de nombre de directorio sean nombres de división, departamento, proyecto, máquina o de inicio de sesión.

```
com.sun.eng
com.apple.quicktime.v2
edu.cmu.cs.bovik.cheese
```

---

#### `Clases`

Los nombres de clase deben ser **sustantivos**. Si hay más de una palabra, la primera letra de cada palabra en mayúscula. Trate de mantener sus nombres de clase simples y descriptivos. Utilice palabras completas: evite siglas y abreviaturas (a menos que la abreviatura sea mucho más utilizada que la forma larga, como URL o HTML).

```
class Raster; 
class ImageSprite;
```

---

#### `Interfaces`

Los nombres de interfaz deben escribirse con cada primera letra en mayúscula, como los nombres de las clases.

```
interface RasterDelegate; 
interface Storing;
```

---

#### `Métodos`

Los nombres de métodos deben ser verbos. La primera letra siempre en minúscula y si son varias palabras, las primeras letras de cada palabra interna en mayúsculas.

```
run(); 
runFast(); 
getBackground();
```

---

#### `Variables`

Excepto para las variables, todas las instancias, clases y constantes de clase están en mayúsculas y minúsculas con una primera letra minúscula. Las palabras internas comienzan con letras mayúsculas. Los nombres de las variables no deben comenzar con caracteres de subrayado `_` o signo de dólar `$`, aunque ambos están permitidos.

Los nombres de variables deben ser breves pero significativos. La elección de un nombre de variable debe ser mnemónica, es decir, diseñada para indicar al observador casual la intención de su uso. Los nombres de variables de un carácter deben evitarse, excepto para las variables temporales "descartables". Los nombres comunes para variables temporales son:

`i`, `j`, `k`, `m`, y `n` para enteros;

`c`, `d`, y `e` para caracteres.

```
int     i;
char    c;
float   myWidth;
```

---

#### `Constantes`

Los nombres de variables declaradas constantes de clase y de constantes ANSI deben ser **todas mayúsculas con palabras separadas por subrayados ("`_`")**. (Las constantes ANSI deben evitarse, para facilitar la depuración.)

```
static final int MIN_WIDTH = 4;
static final int MAX_WIDTH = 999;
static final int GET_THE_CPU = 1;
```

---

No obstante puedes usar otra convención. Se recomienda que sea una de las estandarizadas en la comunidad de programadores y que sea **uniforme**, o sea, que en todo tu código uses la misma convención de nombres.

Answer (score 0):

### Como regla general:

**Para clases y variables:**

1. Caracteres validos: letras, `$`, `_`, números.
2. Identificadores nunca deben comenzar con números
3. Identificadores pueden empezar con simbolos `$` y `_`
4. No utilizar palabras reservadas de JAVA

**Clases:**

1. Uso de covención UperCamelCase(primera letra mayuscula, las demas palabras inician en mayusculas.)

   ```
   public class MiClase{
   }
   ```

**Variables:**

1. Uso de covención lowerCamelCase(primera letra minuscula, las demas palabras inician en mayusculas.) p/e: **nombreCompleto**

   ```
   String nombreCompleto;
   ```