# ¿Por qué me sale error al escribir valueOF?

Tags: java, netbeans

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Aqui esta en la imagen el error estoy empezando recién a utilizar netbeans

Comment: La *`f`*  debe ir en **minúscula**. [Ver el método de la Clase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-). Simplemente basándose en la _convención de nombres_ se puede intuir que ese es el error.

Comment: Si pones el ratón encima de la línea roja, ¿qué dice?

Comment: symbol: method valueOF(String)

Comment: Es **`valueOf`**  no **`valueOF`**. Tienes la **F** final de ese método en mayúscula. Ya que estás empezando, leer algo sobre [convención de nombres](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78423/29967) no vendría mal.

Comment: me sale igual amigo con valueof

Comment: OMG:  `v` minúscula, `a` minúscula,  `l` minúscula, `u` minúscula, `e` minúscula ,  `O` **MAYÚSCULA** , `f` minúscula. Es decir: **`valueOf`**

Comment: igual amigo me saleeee

Comment: Cuando estés escribiendo y pongas el punto antes de la `v` podrás ver una lista de métodos, busca el que diga `valueOf` y selecciónalo. Quizá omitiste algún punto o pusiste algún punto de más o algo.

Comment: @RobinsonRaulCobeñasSandoval como recomendación sería mucho mejor que el código fuese añadido en formato texto y no en imágenes.

Comment: @A.Cedano no me ha quedado claro del todo como se escribe `valueOf`, ¿podrías dar una explicación algo más detallada? :-D

Comment: @SJuan76 me han obligado a tener que escribir una respuesta :) . Espero que ahora se entienda mejor. Saludos.

Answer (score 4):

Veamos:

En la imagen, se ve el método escrito de la siguiente manera:

#### `valueOF`

Se puede observar que la letra **efe** está escrita en mayúsculas.

Si tomamos en cuenta la ***[convención de nombres](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78423/29967)*** de Java con respecto a los métodos podemos leer lo siguiente:

> Los nombres de métodos deben ser verbos, en caso de mezcla con la
>   primera letra minúscula, **con la primera letra de cada palabra interna
>   en mayúsculas**.

Eso quiere decir que en Java **nunca encontraremos un método** escrito con la segunda letra de una palabra en mayúsculas.

La escritura correcta es por lo tanto:

### `valueOf`

es decir, con la letra **efe** en minúscula.

Por otro lado, en los IDEs modernos, como NetBeans, Eclipse, IntelliJ, etc ... cuando estamos escribiendo nuestro código, siempre que ponemos el punto, nos sale una lista de los métodos disponibles para ese elemento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen, cuando yo escribo: `editItem` y a continuación escribo el punto ... o sea: **`editItem.`**  me sale debajo la lista de métodos disponibles para el elemento `editItem`, cuando son muchos métodos, puedo escribir la primera letra del método que me interesa y el IDE se posiciona en el primer método que empieza por esa letra, puedo descender con la flecha, elegir el método que estoy busando, pulsar enter y el método se agrega al código.

**Además**, cuando me posiciono en algún método, me sale otra pantalla flotante explicando lo que hace ese método, incluso, si es un método creado por mí mismo, si lo he documentado correctamente, me saldrá lo que haya escrito en la documentación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código del problema planteado no da más detalles, pero parece referirse a la intención de invocar el método `valueOf` de la [`Clase Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-). Si es ese el método que quieres usar, la forma correcta de escribirlo es **`valueOf`**, como se puede ver en el enlace.

Otra cosa importante es que, cuando presionas el punto `.` a la hora de escribir el código, sólo te salen listados los métodos disponibles para ese elemento. Así que si escribes :

**`dchfechanacimiento.setDate(Date.`**

al poner el punto después de `Date` te saldrá una lista de los métodos disponibles. **Si entre ellos no sale `valueOf`, significa que ese método no existe para ese elemento.** Y si pones cualquier método que esté disponible para un elemento, aunque lo escribas siguiendo la convención de nombres, tendrás derecho a un error.

Espero haberme explicado más claramente.