# Comprobar columna Sqlite y modificar los datos

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Tengo una `Sqlite`:

```
public class SqliteDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DB_NOTAS";
    private static final String TABLE_NOTAS = "NOTAS";
    private static final String TABLE_CATEGORIAS = "CATEGORIAS";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_TITULO = "titulo";
    private static final String COLUMN_NOTAS = "notas";
    private static final String COLUMN_FECHA = "fecha";
    private static final String COLUMN_PERSISTENTE = "persistente";
    private static final String COLUMN_CATEGORIA = "categoria";
    private static final String COLUMN_FAVORITO = "favorito";
    private static final String COLUMN_IMAGEN = "imagen";
    private static final String COLUMN_CREARCATEGORIA = "crearcategoria";


    public SqliteDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_NOTAS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NOTAS + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_TITULO + " TEXT," + COLUMN_NOTAS + " TEXT," + COLUMN_FECHA + " TEXT," + COLUMN_PERSISTENTE + " TEXT," + COLUMN_CATEGORIA + " TEXT," + COLUMN_FAVORITO + " TEXT," + COLUMN_IMAGEN + " TEXT" + ")";
        String CREATE_CATEGORIAS_TABLE = "CREATE    TABLE " + TABLE_CATEGORIAS + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_CREARCATEGORIA + " TEXT" + ")";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_NOTAS_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORIAS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NOTAS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CATEGORIAS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public List<Notas> listNotas() {
        String sql = "select * from " + TABLE_NOTAS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        List<Notas> storeNotas = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
                String titulo = cursor.getString(1);
                String notas = cursor.getString(2);
                String fecha = cursor.getString(3);
                String persistente = cursor.getString(4);
                String categoria = cursor.getString(5);
                String favorito = cursor.getString(6);
                String imagen = cursor.getString(7);
                storeNotas.add(new Notas(id, titulo, notas, fecha, persistente, categoria, favorito, imagen));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return storeNotas;
    }

    public void addNotas(Notas notas) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_TITULO, notas.getTitulo());
        values.put(COLUMN_NOTAS, notas.getNotas());
        values.put(COLUMN_FECHA, notas.getFecha());
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSISTENTE, notas.getPersistente());
        values.put(COLUMN_CATEGORIA, notas.getCategoria());
        values.put(COLUMN_FAVORITO, notas.getFavorito());
        values.put(COLUMN_IMAGEN, notas.getImagen());
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_NOTAS, null, values);
    }

    public void updateNotas(Notas notas) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_TITULO, notas.getTitulo());
        values.put(COLUMN_NOTAS, notas.getNotas());
        values.put(COLUMN_FECHA, notas.getFecha());
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSISTENTE, notas.getPersistente());
        values.put(COLUMN_CATEGORIA, notas.getCategoria());
        values.put(COLUMN_FAVORITO, notas.getFavorito());
        values.put(COLUMN_IMAGEN, notas.getImagen());
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.update(TABLE_NOTAS, values, COLUMN_ID + "    = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(notas.getId())});
    }

    public List<Notas> findNotas() {
        List<Notas> lista_notas = new ArrayList<Notas>();
        String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_NOTAS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_NOTAS + " = " + "notas";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Notas mNotas = null;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            do {
                int id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
                String titulo = cursor.getString(1);
                String notas = cursor.getString(2);
                String fecha = cursor.getString(3);
                String persistente = cursor.getString(4);
                String categoria = cursor.getString(5);
                String favorito = cursor.getString(6);
                String imagen = cursor.getString(7);
                mNotas = new Notas(id, titulo, notas, fecha, persistente, categoria, favorito, imagen);
                lista_notas.add(mNotas);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            db.close();
            cursor.close();
            return lista_notas;
        } else {
            db.close();
            cursor.close();
            return null;
        }

    }

    public void deleteNotas(int id) {
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            db.delete(TABLE_NOTAS, COLUMN_ID + "    = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Y necesito que cuando haga clic en `btn1` compruebe en `COLUMN_CATEGORIA` el *texto* que escriba en `et1` y sustituya todas las palabras que coincidan por las que escriba en `et2`. ¿Cómo puedo realizar esto?

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed1);
        ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed2);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        mDatabase = new SqliteDatabase(Main2Activity.this);


        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
```

He intentando hacer lo siguiente:

Método en `Sqlite`

```
public void CambiarNotasCategorias(String notaAntigua, String NotaNueva) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String sql = "SELECT " + COLUMN_CATEGORIA + " FROM " + TABLE_NOTAS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + " = ?";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{notaAntigua});
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        String val = notaAntigua;
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_CATEGORIA, val);
        db.update(TABLE_NOTAS, values, COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[]{notaAntigua});
        if (!cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CATEGORIA)).equals(NotaNueva)) {
            val = NotaNueva;
            ContentValues values2 = new ContentValues();
            values2.put(COLUMN_CATEGORIA, val);
            db.update(TABLE_NOTAS, values2, COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[]{notaAntigua});
        }

        ContentValues values1 = new ContentValues();
        values1.put(COLUMN_CATEGORIA, val);
        db.update(TABLE_NOTAS, values1, COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[]{notaAntigua});
    }
```

Y lo llamo así desde la `Activity`

```
mDatabase.CambiarNotasCategorias(myInt, "nuevanota");

//myInt = texto que tiene ahora
//nuevanota = texto que debe añadir
```

Pero recibo el siguiente error:

> android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo una que actualizara todas las filas donde el texto coincida:

```
public void CambiarNotasCategorias(String notaAntigua, String NotaNueva) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues data=new ContentValues();
    data.put(COLUMN_CATEGORIAS, NotaNueva);
    db.update(TABLE_NOTAS, data, COLUMN_CATEGORIAS + " = ?", new String[]{notaAntigua});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Algunas cosas:

- No deberías entrar en el cursor asumiendo que éste existirá **siempre** o que **siempre** habrá algo en él. Por lo tanto, en vez de:

  ```
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  ```

  deberías hacer algo como:

  ```
  if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) 
  {
      ...
  }
  ```
- Por otra parte, yo introduciría un bloque `try ... catch` para capturar las posibles excepciones.
- Tampoco estás cerrando los recursos. Así que lo he implementado usando `finally`
- Una pequeña observación sobre la [convención de nombres](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78423/29967). Aunque, esto es *menos* importante, en cuanto que no se traduce en un error del programa en tiempo de compilación o de ejecución, no deja de ser importante. Respeta la *convención de nombres*:

  - Los métodos deben tener la primera letra en minúscula, así que lo he cambiado: `cambiarNotasCategorias`  por `CambiarNotasCategorias`.
  - En cuanto a tus variables, cuando llamas al método le pasas una variable llamada `myInt`... y dices en comentario que es una cadena. Yo, cuando vi el nombre de la variable pensé que era un entero (myInt = miEntero). La otra variable que pasas tampoco cumple la convención de nombres para variables. Sería entonces `nuevaNota` y no `nuevanota`. Eso no da error en el código, pero lo hace más comprensible.

Espero te sea de ayuda.

El método quedaría más o menos así:

```
public void cambiarNotasCategorias(String notaAntigua, String NotaNueva) 
{

    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    Cursor cursor = null;

    try 
    {
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String sql = "SELECT " + COLUMN_CATEGORIA + " FROM " + TABLE_NOTAS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + " = ?";
        cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{notaAntigua});

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) 
        {
            String val = notaAntigua;
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_CATEGORIA, val);
            db.update(TABLE_NOTAS, values, COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[]{notaAntigua});

            if (!cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CATEGORIA)).equals(NotaNueva)) 
            {
                val = NotaNueva;
                ContentValues values2 = new ContentValues();
                values2.put(COLUMN_CATEGORIA, val);
                db.update(TABLE_NOTAS, values2, COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[]{notaAntigua});
            }

            ContentValues values1 = new ContentValues();
            values1.put(COLUMN_CATEGORIA, val);
            db.update(TABLE_NOTAS, values1, COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[]{notaAntigua});

        }

    } 
    catch (final Exception e) 
    {
            // Hacer algo con la execepción (Log, mensaje de error...)
    } 
    finally 
    {
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
    }


}


mDatabase.cambiarNotasCategorias(myInt, nuevaNota);

//myInt = texto que tiene ahora ¿?
//nuevaNota = texto que debe añadir
```