# tengo un error al llamar a mi función en java

Tags: java, funciones

```
class NotaProg1 {
    public static double NotaProg1Cont (double eval1,double eval2,double 
ent,double clase){
        if (eval2 < 5)
        {
             return 0;
        }
        else
        { 
             return (eval1* 0.20)+(eval2 *0.5)+ (ent * 0.2) + (clase * 0.1);
        }
    }

    public static double NotaProg1(double evalCont,double examenFinal){

        if (evalCont == 1)
        {
             return NotaProg1Cont();
        }
        else
        {
             return examenFinal;
        }

     }

public static void main (String args[]){
     double eval1=7.6;
     double eval2=7;
     double ent=9.5;
     double clase=8.3;
     double evalCont= 1;
     double examenFinal=9;

     System.out.println("NotaProg1Cont=" + NotaProg1Cont(eval1,eval2,ent,clase));
     System.out.println("NotaProg=" + NotaProg1(evalCont,examenFinal));

 }// final de main

 }
```

Cuando llamo a la función "`NotaProg1Cont`" dentro de mi otra función "NotaProg", me sale el siguiente error:

> "**The method NotaProg1Cont(double, double, double, double) in the
>   type NotaProg1 is not applicable for the arguments ()**"

Comment: Cuando llamas a `NotaProg1Cont`  debes pasarle **cuatro argumentos del tipo double**. Al llamarlo así: `return NotaProg1Cont();` ¿dónde están los argumentos que espera? P. D.: Más adelante revisa el tema de la [convención de nombres en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78423/29967) para que tu código sea más claro.

Comment: @DanielGarcia  que es lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: quiero llamar a la función NotaProg1Cont definida anteriormente en mi función NotaProf1

Comment: @DanielGarciaGonzalez edita la pregunta con los detalles que añades en la zona de comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

El error:

> The method NotaProg1Cont(double, double, double, double) in the type
> NotaProg1 is not applicable for the arguments ()

indica que no le estás pasando al método los cuatro argumentos del tipo `double` con los que el mismo ha sido definido.

En efecto, si `NotaProg1Cont` está definido así:

```
public static double NotaProg1Cont (double eval1,double eval2,double 
ent,double clase){
```

significa que cuando lo llamas, debes pasarle **cuatro argumentos del tipo double**.

Pero al llamarlo así:

```
return NotaProg1Cont();
```

¿dónde están los argumentos que espera?

Tienes que llamarlo como haces aquí:

```
NotaProg1Cont(eval1,eval2,ent,clase);
```

Ahí sí le estas pasando sus cuatro argumentos.

**Nota:** Si haces esto:

```
return NotaProg1Cont(eval1,eval2,ent,clase);
```

es posible que tu programa se quede en un bucle infinito en algunos casos, quizá ahí debas redefinir el valor de las variables o pasar otros parámetros diferentes, eso depende del contexto de tu programa.

---

P. D.: Más adelante revisa el tema de la [convención de nombres en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78423/29967) para que tu código sea más claro.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, perdón por mi vocabulario, me lo revisaré,pero este es mi primer programa; pero siguiendo con el problema, cuando meto los 4 argumentos, me sale otros 4 errores, diciendo que los argumentos no pueden ser resueltos como variables.

Comment: Los argumentos que pongas deben existir en el contexto en que los estás usando. Si usas variables que no sean de la clase, que pertenezcan a otro método, te dará error. En cambio, si lo llamas con variables declaradas en el contexto o con valores directos como por ejemplo: `return NotaProg1Cont(10.5,12.7,9.2,5.5);`