# Por que no me resuelve la variable sumaserie

Tags: java

```
package org.ip.sesion04;

public class SumaSerie {
    public static double sumaSerie(int i)
    {
        double SumaSerie = i/(i+1);
        return SumaSerie;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int i=0;
        double SumaSerie;
        System.out.println("i\t SUMA");
        System.out.println();
        for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i+"\t"+SumaSerie);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola Jose. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. No está claro lo que preguntas. Añade el comportamiento que esperas y lo que estas obteniendo. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más informacion. Un saludo

Comment: Dos cosas que cambiaría yo. Lo primero, aunque declares SumaSerie como double, si divides 2 int, el resultado es un int (puedes hacer un cast para solucionarlo). Otra cosa y la más importante, cambia el nombre de la variable, es un error llamarle como en nombre de la clase. Llámalo sumaSerie o como más te guste, pero no igual que la clase ya que te puede dar errores como está pasando.

Answer (score 1):

El principal error de tu código es este:

**`System.out.println(i+"\t"+SumaSerie);`**

deberías llamar al método `sumaSerie()` pasándole su argumento.

Luego, la lógica de tu programa no funciona, el resultado de suma serie será siempre cero, porque la división entre dos enteros cuando el valor es menor que uno da como resultado cero en Java. Debes entonces hacer un casting con al menos uno de los operandos aquí:

```
double SumaSerie = i/(i+1);
```

En cuanto al bucle `for`, puedes escribirlo así:

```
for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
```

declarando la variable `i` y asignándole el valor `1` al mismo tiempo. Declarar `int i=0;`  para luego cambiar su valor otra vez al iniciar el bucle `for` es innecesario.

Por otra parte, es importante que respetes la convención de nombres en Java (ver [¿Cuál es la convención para escribir variables en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/78420/29967)).

---

### SOLUCIÓN COMPLETA

```
public class SumaSerie {
    public  static double sumaSerie(int i)
    {
        double dblSumaSerie = (double)i/(i+1); //Casting a double de uno de los operandos
        return dblSumaSerie;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("i\t SUMA");
        System.out.println();

        for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i+"\t"+sumaSerie(i)); //Llamada al método con su argumento
        }
    }

}
```

### Resultado:

```
i    SUMA

1   0.5
2   0.6666666666666666
3   0.75
4   0.8
5   0.8333333333333334
6   0.8571428571428571
7   0.875
8   0.8888888888888888
9   0.9
10  0.9090909090909091
```