# Cuál es el error en mi programa?

Tags: java, date

Buenas os comento he creado un programa para que saque los dias restantes para mi proximo cumpleaños cogiendo la fecha actual y yo pasandole la fecha de nacimiento. Os adjunto el codigo entero.

```
public class Clase {

    private String Nombre;
    private String PrimerApellido;
    private String SegundoApellido;
    private String Direccion;
    private String Poblacion;
    private int Telefono;
    private Date FechaNacimiento;
    private int Foto;
    private int Diasrestantes;


    public Clase(String nombre, String primerApellido, String segundoApellido, String direccion, String poblacion, int telefono, Date fechaNacimiento, int foto, int diasrestantes) {
        Nombre = nombre;
        PrimerApellido = primerApellido;
        SegundoApellido = segundoApellido;
        Direccion = direccion;
        Poblacion = poblacion;
        Telefono = telefono;
        FechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
        Foto = foto;
        Diasrestantes = diasrestantes;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        Nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getPrimerApellido() {
        return PrimerApellido;
    }

    public void setPrimerApellido(String primerApellido) {
        PrimerApellido = primerApellido;
    }

    public String getSegundoApellido() {
        return SegundoApellido;
    }

    public void setSegundoApellido(String segundoApellido) {
        SegundoApellido = segundoApellido;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return Direccion;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        Direccion = direccion;
    }

    public String getPoblacion() {
        return Poblacion;
    }

    public void setPoblacion(String poblacion) {
        Poblacion = poblacion;
    }

    public int getTelefono() {
        return Telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(int telefono) {
        Telefono = telefono;
    }

    public Date getFechaNacimiento() {
        return FechaNacimiento;
    }

    public void setFechaNacimiento(Date fechaNacimiento) {
        FechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
    }

    public int getFoto() {
        return Foto;
    }

    public void setFoto(int foto) {
        Foto = foto;
    }

    public long getDiasrestantes() {
        return Diasrestantes;
    }

    public void setDiasrestantes(int diasrestantes) {
        Diasrestantes = diasrestantes;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Clase{" +
                "Nombre='" + Nombre + '\'' +
                ", PrimerApellido='" + PrimerApellido + '\'' +
                ", SegundoApellido='" + SegundoApellido + '\'' +
                ", Direccion='" + Direccion + '\'' +
                ", Poblacion='" + Poblacion + '\'' +
                ", Telefono=" + Telefono +
                ", FechaNacimiento=" + FechaNacimiento +
                ", Foto=" + Foto +
                ", Diasrestantes=" + Diasrestantes +
                '}';
    }

    public  String  FechaActual() throws ParseException {

        String fechaActual = "";

        Calendar fecha = new GregorianCalendar();

        int annio = fecha.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        int mes =fecha.get(Calendar.MONTH);

        int dia = fecha.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        fechaActual = annio + "-" + (mes+1) + "-" + dia;
        System.out.println(fechaActual);
        return (fechaActual);

    }

        public  long Diasrestantes() throws ParseException{
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date fechaInicial = dateFormat.parse(FechaActual());
        Date fechaFinal = dateFormat.parse(fechaclase());
        int dias = abs ((int) ((fechaFinal.getTime()-fechaInicial.getTime())/86400000));
            while (dias>365){
                dias=dias-365;

            }

            Diasrestantes =(int) dias;
            return dias;


    }

    public   String fechaclase() throws ParseException{
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        String reportDate = dateFormat.format(FechaNacimiento);
        String annion = reportDate.substring(0,4);
        String mesn = reportDate.substring(5,7);
        String dian = reportDate.substring(8,10);

        String fechanacimiento = annion + "-" + mesn + "-" + dian;
        System.out.println(fechanacimiento);


        return fechanacimiento;
    }

    }
```

//MainClass

```
public class MainClass {

   public static void main (String[]args)throws ParseException{

       SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
       String Fechanacimiento = "2000-10-27";
       Date fecha= formato.parse(Fechanacimiento);

       Clase companyero = new Clase("Christian","Guijarro","Amor","C/Bruselas","Alicante",999999999,fecha,0,0);
       companyero.Diasrestantes();
       System.out.println("Los dias que faltan son "+companyero.getDiasrestantes());

   }
}
```

Lo que no entiendo es que si lo muestro por la pantalla con estos datos por ejemplo me sale que la diferencia de dias es 3, cuando deberia ser uno. 
Que tengo mal en el codigo?

Comment: Fecha actual te devuelve el valor de hoy??? otra cosa, no es NADA recomendable poner datos reales de una persona. Deberías borrar al menos el número de teléfono.

Comment: Si me duelve la fecha actual, Con un system out esto es lo que imprime por pantalla 2017-10-26

Answer (score 0):

Este código resolvería tu problema.

La fuente original es esta: [Calculate the span of time from today until your birthday](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java_Date_Time/Example/Date/Calculate_the_span_of_time_from_today_until_your_birthday.htm)

Le he hecho una simple modificación para que indique un mensaje cuando la fecha actual coincida con el día de nacimiento (eso ocurre cuando `totalDias=365`).

Puedes introducir el código en un método que se llama por ejemplo `calcularDiasRestantes` que reciba como parámetro una cadena con la fecha de nacimiento o un objeto fecha directamente...

```
    public  long calcularDiasRestantes(String strFecha) 
    {

        /*Fecha actual.*/
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

        /*Fecha de nacimiento recibida.*/
        LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.parse(strFecha);

        LocalDate nextBDay = birthday.withYear(today.getYear());

        /*Si el cumpleaños ya ocurrió este año, agrega 1 año*/
        if (nextBDay.isBefore(today) || nextBDay.isEqual(today)) 
        {
            nextBDay = nextBDay.plusYears(1);
        }

        Period p = Period.between(today, nextBDay);
        long totalDias = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(today, nextBDay);

        return totalDias;
    }
```

#### Ejemplo de programa completo:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*Fecha actual*/
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

        /*Fecha de nacimiento. Ambas formas son válidas*/
        //LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.of(2000, Month.OCTOBER, 27);
        LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.parse("2000-10-27");
        LocalDate nextBDay = birthday.withYear(today.getYear());

        /*Si el cumpleaños ya ocurrió este año, agrega 1 año*/
        if (nextBDay.isBefore(today) || nextBDay.isEqual(today)) {
            nextBDay = nextBDay.plusYears(1);
        }

        Period p = Period.between(today, nextBDay);
        long totalDias = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(today, nextBDay);

        /*Cuando totalDias=365 hoy es el cumpleaños*/

        if (totalDias == 365) {

            System.out.println("¡Su cumpleaños es hoy. Felicidades!");

        } else {

            System.out.println("Restan " + p.getMonths() + " meses, y "
                    + p.getDays() + " días para su próximo cumpleaños. ("
                    + totalDias + " días en total)");
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Resultado:

En cualquier fecha, algo parecido a esto:

```
Restan 0 meses, y 1 días para su próximo cumpleaños. (1 días en total)
```

Cuando la fecha coincida con el día de nacimiento:

```
¡Su cumpleaños es hoy. Felicidades!
```

---

**Nota sobre la convención de nombres**

Tu código no está adaptado a la *convención de nombres en Java*. Es bueno que apliques esta práctica recomendada, a pesar de que no influya en errores del programa. Para más detalles sobre esto puedes leer esta pregunta y su respuesta: [¿Cuál es la convención para escribir variables en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/78420/29967)

Comment: Gracias pero hay un problema, estoy trabajando en android studio y las librerias java no me las reconoce, asi que ese codigo no puedo utilizarlo.

Comment: @DPlay97 [`LocalDate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalDate.html) fue agregado en la API 26 de Android, si actualizas tu proyecto a la API 26 debería funcionar, o bien buscar otra forma de hacerlo. Como ves, de esta forma es una operación muy sencilla.