# ¿cómo crear un constructor personalizado en Java?

Tags: java, javafx

En una clase llamada Monedas se tienen los siguientes miembros:
a. Dos variables privadas de tipo cadena llamadas país y moneda, el valor de las variables
deberá se digitado desde el teclado. El código para solicitar ese valor debe escribirlo en
la clase del método Main.
b. Cree un constructor personalizado con dos parámetros de tipo String que acepte los
parámetros correspondientes a las variables de la clase y que muestre un mensaje. Por
ejemplo “La moneda de curso legal de El Salvador es el dolar”, en este mensaje debe
concatenar las variables que recibirá en el parámetro.
Implemente la clase.

```
import java.util.*;

class monedaPais{
   private String moneda, pais;

   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static void main(String args[])
   {
   System.out.println("ingrese el pais");
   pais = sc.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Ingrese la moneda");
   moneda = sc.nextLine();
   }

    public monedaPais (string moneda, string pais){

         this.moneda = moneda; 
          this.pais = pais;

        }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi solución sería:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MonedaPais {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Escribe el país: ");
        String p = kbd.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Escribe la moneda: ");
        String m = kbd.nextLine();

        Moneda moneda = new Moneda(p, m);

    }

}

class Moneda {
    private String pais, moneda;

    public Moneda(String pais, String moneda) {
        this.pais = pais;
        this.moneda = moneda;

        System.out.println("La moneda de curso legal de " + pais + " es el " + moneda);
    }
}
```

Un consejo: Los nombres de las clases siempre empiezan por Mayúscula. Eclipse por ejemplo, te lo advierte cuando intentas crearla.

Comment: aa bueno gracias amigo

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que se trata de un ejercicio. Pero ten en cuenta que generalmente esto no se hace así, por ejemplo el constructor no suele  usarse para imprimir cosas, por lo general las clases tienen un método `toString` o métodos `get` para obtener valores desde dentro de ellas.

También, el método `main` no iría en esta clase generalmente.

He renombrado la clase llamándola `MonedaPais`, ya que la *[convención de nombres](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78423/29967)* es importante para una mejor comprensión y organización del código.

Veamos entonces un código con lo que te faltaría:

#### Clase principal

```
import java.util.*;
class MonedaPais { //Generalmente la clase principal se llama Main

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("ingrese el pais");
        String pais = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese la moneda");
        String moneda = sc.nextLine();

        /*Cerrar scanner*/
        sc.close();
        /*Implementar Clase
         *aquí creamos una instancia de la clase Monea
         *pasándole dos parámetros al constructor
         *que son los valores escritos en el scanner
        */
        Moneda m = new Moneda(moneda, pais);
    }

}
```

#### Clase Moneda

```
public class Moneda {

    private String moneda;
    private String pais;

    /*
     *Constructor con dos parámetros
     *Cuando se cree una instancia de la clase con estos dos parámetros
     *se construirá una instancia de ella, haciendo lo que haya aquí
     *IMPORTANTE: Los constructores no suelen usarse para imprimir cosas
     *Las clases deben estar dotadas de métodos para ello
     *aquí se hace así por requerimiento de la pregunta
    */
    public Moneda(String moneda, String pais) {

        this.moneda = moneda;
        this.pais = pais;

        /*Imprimir valores*/
        System.out.println("La moneda de curso legal de: " + pais + " es: " + moneda);

    }
}
```

#### Out

```
ingrese el pais
Japón
Ingrese la moneda
Yen
La moneda de curso legal de: Japón es: Yen
```

Comment: oo si  me falta  todavia  muchas gracias