# Por que me sale este error en este problema de java?

Tags: java

No entiendo, el ejercicio  me da 4 errores.El enunciado del ejercicio es el siguiente:

En una clase llamada Monedas se tienen los siguientes miembros:
a. Dos variables privadas de tipo cadena llamadas país y moneda, el valor de las variables deberá se digitado desde el teclado. El código para solicitar ese valor debe escribirlo en la clase del método Main.
b. Cree un constructor personalizado con dos parámetros de tipo String que acepte los parámetros correspondientes a las variables de la clase y que muestre un mensaje. Por ejemplo “La moneda de curso legal de El Salvador es el dolar”, en este mensaje debe concatenar las variables que recibirá en el parámetro.   Implemente la clase.

```
class MonedaPais {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Escribe el país: ");
    String pa = ob.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Escribe la moneda: ");
    String mon = ob.nextLine();

    Moneda moneda = new Moneda(pa, mon);

}
```

}

```
class MonedaPais10 {
private String pais, moneda;

public static void main(String pais, String moneda) {
    this.pais = pais;
    this.moneda = moneda;

    System.out.println("La moneda de curso legal de " + pais + " es el " + moneda);
}
```

Los errores que salen son:

> MonedaPais10.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
>           Moneda moneda = new Moneda(pa, mon);
>           ^   symbol:   class Moneda   location: class MonedaPais MonedaPais10.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
>           Moneda moneda = new Moneda(pa, mon);
>                               ^   symbol:   class Moneda   location: class MonedaPais MonedaPais10.java:24: error: non-static variable this
>   cannot be referenced from a static context
>           this.pais = pais;
>           ^ MonedaPais10.java:25: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
>           this.moneda = moneda;
>           ^ 4 errors

[image: me podrían ayudar quiero saber por que me da ese error]

Comment: hay muchisimos problemas, sobre todo principalmente un desorden de lo que tenes que hacer. el primer error es que no existe la clase moneda... existe?

Comment: Me parece que tu problema [fue resuelto aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/114818/29967). No entiendo por qué estás planteando de nuevo el mismo problema. Además, te di una explicación sobre una futura organización de tu programa, indicando que el método `main` debería ir en una `Clase` independiente de tus otras clases. Aunque eso no es motivo de fallo, pero puede serlo de confusión a la hora de aprender programar.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que estás un poco confundido con lo que es un void main y con lo que es un constructor, en la clase monedaPais10 tienes un main al igual que en la clase monedaPais,

El segundo tendría que quedar así

```
class MonedaPais10 {
private String pais, moneda;

public MoneaPais10(String pais, String moneda) {
    this.pais = pais;
    this.moneda = moneda;

    System.out.println("La moneda de curso legal de " + pais + " es el " + moneda);
}
```

para poder inicializar un objeto con parametros ya que ese es tu constructor

En segundo lugar usas la clase Moneda en la tu main y no pusiste nada sobre una clase moneda.