# Java-You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: java, mysql

Buenas. Ando haciendo un programa en java que conecta con una base de datos MySQL y me está dando problemas hacer un select. El código es el siguiente:

```
try{ 
        St = conexion.createStatement();
        ResultSet = St.executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM `lxgtt` WHERE web='google' AND clave='user'"); 
        while (rs.next()){ 
            web=rs.getString(1);
            mayus=rs.getString(2);
            numeros=rs.getString(3);
            letras=rs.getString(4);
            simbolos=rs.getString(5);
            modificacion=rs.getString(6);
            clave=rs.getString(7);
            }
    } catch (Exception e ) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
```

Y el error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE web='google'' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2486)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2444)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1381)
at Model.conexionHost.consultaWeb(conexionHost.java:75)
at view.ventanaPrincipal.comprobarWebHost(ventanaPrincipal.java:882)
at view.ventanaPrincipal.clickBoton(ventanaPrincipal.java:1002)
at view.ventanaPrincipal$16.mouseReleased(ventanaPrincipal.java:577)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Si realizo la consulta tal cual directamente en MySQL me da resultado, pero no desde Java y no consigo encontrar el error (la conexión con la bd e inserción de datos los hace correctamente).

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Quita las dos comillas que rodean a `lxgtt`.

Comment: No, sigue igual. He estado probando a poner y quitar comillas pero nada, sigue dando el mismo fallo.

Comment: Ya vi tu error, no asignaste nombre de variable al `Resultset`: Debes corregirlo así: **`ResultSet rs= St.executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM lxgtt WHERE web='google' AND clave='user'");`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para manejar errores en sentencias *SQL* mejor capturar excepciones *SQL*. Un fallo podría estar en las comillas de la cadena de caracteres de la sentencia *SQL*, puedes (opcionalmente) crearte un String con la sentencia y pasarla por parámetro. También he declarado las variables `Statement` y `ResultSet` de la siguiente manera:

```
try{ 
        // Preparamos la consulta 
        Statement st = conexion.createStatement();
        String selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM lxgtt WHERE web=google AND clave=user";
        ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery (selectSQL); 
        // Recorremos el resultado, mientras haya registros para leer
        while (rs.next()){ 
            web=rs.getString(1);
            mayus=rs.getString(2);
            numeros=rs.getString(3);
            letras=rs.getString(4);
            simbolos=rs.getString(5);
            modificacion=rs.getString(6);
            clave=rs.getString(7);
            }
    } catch (SQLException ex ) { 
        System.out.println(ex.getErrorCode()); // si tu aplicación es por consola
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No asignaste nombre al objeto `Resultset` que estás creando aquí:

<s>`ResultSet = St.executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM`lxgtt`WHERE web='google' AND clave='user'");`</s>

Y que luego usas para leer los resultados, pensando que se llama `rs`:

```
while (rs.next()){ ....
```

Debes entonces asignarle el nombre:

```
ResultSet rs = St.executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM `lxgtt` WHERE web='google' AND clave='user'");
```

También la variable `St` imagino que la tienes declarada más arriba así:

```
Statement St = null;
```

---

**Nota:** Ten en cuenta aplicar una convención de nombres adecuada. El código será más fácil de leer y analizar, no sólo por ti, sino por cualquier programador.

En Java, la convención de nombres indica que los nombres de `Clases` empiezan con mayúsculas, y los nombres de variables por minúsculas, por tanto, tu variable  `St` no cumple con dicha convención de nombres.

Para más detalles: [¿Cuál es la convención para escribir variables en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/78420/29967)