# Error Too many connections

Tags: java, mysql

estaba creando mis querys y de pronto 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el asunto es que no puedo seguir con el desarrollo de mi programa

les dejo el codigode mi conexion

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Conexion {


Connection cnx;

 public Connection getCnx(){
      try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            cnx=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myl", "root", "");

          }catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error de Acceso:\n No hay conexion a la base de datos\n:"+ ex,"Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

      }

           return cnx;
           }

public void closeCnx() throws SQLException{

      if(cnx != null){

              cnx.close();

    }
}
```

}

y este es el codigo de mis query

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Querys {


Conexion CNX=new Conexion();
PreparedStatement SQL;
List validation = new ArrayList();
Connection con = CNX.getCnx();
Object[] titulos = {"id","nombre","tipo","fecha","hora"};
DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(null,titulos);

  public List LogIn(String user) throws SQLException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    String queryPassword = "SELECT users, pass FROM log WHERE users='"+user+"'";
    SQL = con.prepareStatement(queryPassword);
    ResultSet result = SQL.executeQuery();
    String PassDB = null;
    String UserDB = null;
   if (result.next()){
          UserDB=result.getString("users");
          PassDB=result.getString("pass");
          validation.add(UserDB);
          validation.add(PassDB);

   }
   CNX.closeCnx();
    return validation;
  }

  public DefaultTableModel buscarTorneo(String fecha) throws SQLException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

      String queryPassword = "SELECT * FROM `torneo` WHERE fecha='"+fecha+"'";
    SQL = con.prepareStatement(queryPassword);
    ResultSet result = SQL.executeQuery();
   if (result.next()){

          dtm.addRow(new Object[]{
            result.getString("id"),
            result.getString("nombre"),
            result.getString("tipo"),
            result.getString("fecha"),
            result.getString("hora")
   });
   }
    CNX.closeCnx();
    return dtm;
    }

        public void crearTorneo(String nombre,String tipo, String fecha,String h) throws SQLException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
     String query = "INSERT INTO torneo (nombre, tipo, fecha, hora) "
                + "VALUES ('"+nombre+"','"+tipo+"','"+fecha+"','"+h+"');";
     SQL = con.prepareStatement(query);
    SQL.execute();
    CNX.closeCnx();
      }
```

}

Espero puedan ayudarme ya que he buscado por todas partes pero no encuentro información concisa al respecto.

Geacias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno, tu código cuenta con varios problemas como lo tienes estructurado entre ellos uno de lo mas graves y que hace que te salga el error de las conexiones es un `PreparedStatement` global que usas en todos los métodos y que nunca cierras. ¡**Nunca**! vuelvas a poner un `PreparedStatement` o un `ResultSet` global. No se necesita pues después de terminar de usarlos en un método deberás cerrarlos.

Para cerrar las conexiones lo debes hacer al contrario de como se abrieron cuando vas a realizar una consulta lo haces abriendo primera la conexion, despues el PreparedStatement y por ultimo el Resulset en caso de necesitarse visto esto se deben cerrar primero el resultSet segundo el PreparedStatamente y tercero la Conexión.

El otro problema que tienes en tu código es que estas pensando que siempre todo va a fluir con normalidad y aunque eso es lo debido no siempre sucede, te digo esto porque tu cierras las conexiones después de ejecutar la sentencia SQL pero ¿Que pasa si sale un error al ejecutarla o un error antes de poder ejecutarla? La respuesta es te quedaría la conexión abierta porque nunca se llegó a la línea que cierra.

Por tal motivo ¡**Siempre**! cierra tu conexión en un bloque `finally` siempre preguntando si es nula para que no generes mas errores.

Te dejo tu código con los cambios explicado en la respuesta:

**Postadata**: En la documentación de java dice que si cierras el statement se cierra el resultSet y asi sucesivamente pero he tenido varios golpes de pecho por hacer caso a eso.

Por ultimo y no menos grave es que siempre que creas una instancia de Query `Query query = new Query();` estas creando una conexión a la base de datos en la sentencia `Connection con = CNX.getCnx();` lo que es delicado porque si no realizas ninguna acción la conexión nunca se cerrará.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Conexion {

    public Connection getCnx() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myl", "root", "");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error de Acceso:\n No hay conexion a la base de datos\n:" + ex, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void closeCnx(Connection cnx) throws SQLException {
        if (cnx != null) {
            cnx.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Y la clase Query

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Querys {

    Conexion CNX = new Conexion();


    Object[] titulos = {"id", "nombre", "tipo", "fecha", "hora"};
    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(null, titulos);

    public List LogIn(String user) throws SQLException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        Connection con = CNX.getCnx();

        List validation = new ArrayList();
        PreparedStatement sql = null;
        ResultSet result = null;
        try {
            String queryPassword = "SELECT users, pass FROM log WHERE users='" + user + "'";
            sql = con.prepareStatement(queryPassword);
            result = sql.executeQuery();
            String PassDB = null;
            String UserDB = null;
            if (result.next()) {
                UserDB = result.getString("users");
                PassDB = result.getString("pass");
                validation.add(UserDB);
                validation.add(PassDB);

            }
        } finally {
            if (result != null) {
                result.close();
            }

            if (sql != null) {
                sql.close();
            }

            CNX.closeCnx(con);
        }
        return validation;
    }

    public DefaultTableModel buscarTorneo(String fecha) throws SQLException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        Connection con = CNX.getCnx();

        PreparedStatement sql = null;
        ResultSet result = null;

        try {
            String queryPassword = "SELECT * FROM `torneo` WHERE fecha='" + fecha + "'";
            sql = con.prepareStatement(queryPassword);
            result = sql.executeQuery();
            if (result.next()) {

                dtm.addRow(new Object[]{
                    result.getString("id"),
                    result.getString("nombre"),
                    result.getString("tipo"),
                    result.getString("fecha"),
                    result.getString("hora")
                });
            }
        } finally {
            if (result != null) {
                result.close();
            }

            if (sql != null) {
                sql.close();
            }

            CNX.closeCnx(con);
        }
        return dtm;
    }

    public void crearTorneo(String nombre, String tipo, String fecha, String h) throws SQLException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        String query = "INSERT INTO torneo (nombre, tipo, fecha, hora) "
                + "VALUES ('" + nombre + "','" + tipo + "','" + fecha + "','" + h + "');";

        Connection con = CNX.getCnx();

        PreparedStatement sql = null;

        try {
            sql = con.prepareStatement(query);
            sql.execute();
        } finally {
            if (sql != null) {
                sql.close();
            }

            CNX.closeCnx(con);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No vendría mal una pequeña nota sobre la **[convención de nombres](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78423/29967)**.

Comment: @jizalde me sirvió mucho tu aclaración con respecto al correcto cierre de las conexiones (primero por `resultSet`, segundo `preparedStatemen`  y por ultimo la conexion). ademas de nunca dejar las variables globales ya que siempre quedan abiertas.

Gracias por todo!

Answer (score 0):

Generalmente esto indica que no se esta cerrando las conexiones correctamente, asegúrate de que se ejecuta el `cnx.close();` y que no se esta saltando directamente a la excepción.

Para una solución temporal aumenta el limite de conexiones a la base de datos y reinicia el MySQL para que se cierren las sesiones.

Comment: Para que la pregunta sea más completa y sirva de ayuda a otros usuarios, sería bueno que indicases cómo se aumentaría el límite de conexiones. ¿Es algo que se haría en MySQL o programáticamente desde Java? Te recomiendo que leas [answer] donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar tus publicaciones.