# Mostrar objetos con el método toString()

Tags: java, string, object

Buenas.
Mi duda es por qué si todos los métodos devuelven un "new Complejo", los métodos suma y divEscalar pueden sacar el resultado por pantalla sin necesidad de añadir ".toString()", y los demás lo necesitan.

Gracias.

```
public final class Complejo extends Number {
//atributos
private float x;
private float y;

//constructores
public Complejo(){
    x=0;
    y=0;
}

public Complejo(float rx, float iy){
    x=rx;
    y=iy;
}


//métodos:

//Norma
public final float norma(){
    return (float)Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y);
}

public final float norma(Complejo c) { 
    return (float)Math.sqrt(c.x*c.x+c.y*c.y); 
} 

//Conjugado
public final Complejo conjugado(){
    Complejo r = new Complejo(x,-y);
    return r;
}

public final Complejo conjugado(Complejo c){
    Complejo r = new Complejo (c.x, -c.y);
    return r;
}


// obligatorios (son abstractos en Number): 

public final double doubleValue() { 
    return (double)norma(); 
} 

public final float floatValue() {
    return norma(); 
} 

public final int intValue() { 
    return (int)norma(); 
} 

public final long longValue() { 
    return (long)norma(); 
} 

public final String toString() {
    if (y<0) 
        return x+"-i"+(-y);
    else
    return x+"+i"+y;
} 


// Operaciones matemáticas 

public static final Complejo suma(Complejo c1, Complejo c2) { 
    return new Complejo(c1.x+c2.x,c1.y+c2.y); 
} 

public static final Complejo resta(Complejo c1, Complejo c2) {
    return new Complejo(c1.x-c2.x,c1.y-c2.y); 
} 

public static final Complejo producto(Complejo c1, Complejo c2) { 
    return new Complejo(c1.x*c2.x-c1.y*c2.y,c1.x*c2.y+c1.y*c2.x); 
} 


// Nos va a venir bien para aprender excepciones... como división por cero! 

public static final Complejo divEscalar(Complejo c, float f) { 
    return new Complejo(c.x/f,c.y/f); 
} 

public static final Complejo cociente(Complejo c1, Complejo c2) { 
    float x = c1.x*c2.x+c1.y*c2.y; 
    float y = -c1.x*c2.y+c1.y*c2.x; 
    float n = c2.x*c2.x+c2.y*c2.y; 
    Complejo r = new Complejo(x,y); 

    return divEscalar(r,n); 
}
}
```

---

```
public class EjemploComplejos {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Complejo c1 = new Complejo(4,-3);
System.out.println(c1+"\tNorma="+c1.norma());

Complejo c2 = new Complejo(-2,5);
System.out.println(c2+"\tNorma="+c2.norma());


System.out.println("("+c1+")/4 :"+Complejo.divEscalar(c1,4));    
System.out.println("Suma  : "+Complejo.suma(c1,c2));
System.out.println("Resta : "+Complejo.resta(c1,c2).toString());    
System.out.println("Multip: "+Complejo.producto(c1,c2).toString());    
System.out.println("Divis : "+Complejo.cociente(c1,c2).toString());  
} 

}
```

Comment: Hay cosas que no explicas sobre tu código y es difícil de entenderlo. Algo a tener en cuenta, es que si tenemos un método toString definido, al mostrar el objeto sin mas (sin invocar nada), ejecutara por defecto este método. Da igual si llamas explícitamente al método toString(), si no lo haces, será llamado de todas formas. Podría decirte más, pero, tu código está desordenado y le faltan partes para poder comprenderlo bien. En resumen, siempre debería funcionar sin llamar a toString(). Si tienes problemas, agrega más información y te ayudaremos.

Comment: Como ha dicho @RobertGomez, a tu pregunta la falta información para darte una respuesta concisa. Por ejemplo, ¿tienes un método `toString` definido en la clase `Complejo`? ¿Cómo es ese método?. También, recomendaría que apliques adecuadamente la [convención de nombres](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/78420/29967) en tu programa, al leerlo, tus métodos parecen clases. No aplicar la convención de nombres hace que escribas un código confuso, díficil de analizar y comprender para los otros ¡y también para ti! cuando el programa crezca.

Comment: Gracias por molestaros!
Espero haber dejado más claro el código ahora.

Comment: Vale, había sido un error del IDE al correr el programa. Funciona todo como debía, por éso antes me estaba destrozando los nervios... -_-
Gracias, y disculpad las molestias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... por qué si todos los métodos devuelven un "new Complejo", los
>   métodos suma y divEscalar pueden sacar el resultado por pantalla sin
>   necesidad de añadir ".toString()", y los demás lo necesitan.

Si hacemos una prueba de concepto de tu código, vemos que los valores devueltos por los métodos:

- `divEscalar()`
- `suma()`
- `resta()`
- `producto()`
- `cociente()`

**son los mismos, tanto si usas `toString` como si no lo usas**.

La prueba hecha es esta:

### Sin `toString()`:

```
Complejo c2 = new Complejo(-2,5);
System.out.println("SIN toString()");

System.out.println(c2+"\tNorma="+c2.norma());
System.out.println("("+c1+")/4 :"+Complejo.divEscalar(c1,4));    
System.out.println("Suma  : "+Complejo.suma(c1,c2));
System.out.println("Resta : "+Complejo.resta(c1,c2));    
System.out.println("Multip: "+Complejo.producto(c1,c2));    
System.out.println("Divis : "+Complejo.cociente(c1,c2));
```

**Resultado:**

```
SIN toString()

-2.0+i5.0   Norma=5.3851647
(4.0-i3.0)/4 :1.0-i0.75
Suma  : 2.0+i2.0
Resta : 6.0-i8.0
Multip: 7.0+i26.0
Divis : -0.79310346-i0.4827586
```

---

### Con `toString()`:

```
System.out.println("\nCON toString()");
System.out.println(c2+"\tNorma="+c2.norma());
System.out.println("("+c1+")/4 :"+Complejo.divEscalar(c1,4).toString());    
System.out.println("Suma  : "+Complejo.suma(c1,c2).toString());
System.out.println("Resta : "+Complejo.resta(c1,c2).toString());    
System.out.println("Multip: "+Complejo.producto(c1,c2).toString());    
System.out.println("Divis : "+Complejo.cociente(c1,c2).toString());
```

**Resultado:**

```
CON toString()

-2.0+i5.0   Norma=5.3851647
(4.0-i3.0)/4 :1.0-i0.75
Suma  : 2.0+i2.0
Resta : 6.0-i8.0
Multip: 7.0+i26.0
Divis : -0.79310346-i0.4827586
```

En cambio, al método:

- `norma()`

No se le puede aplicar `toString()`, porque dicho método no es aplicable a los tipos primitivos, y `norma()` está declarado en la clase como del tipo primitivo `float`:

```
public final float norma(){
    /...
}
```

---

### Conclusión

El problema que planteas no existe. Te devuelve lo mismo con y sin `toString()`.

Comment: Sí, justo lo había comprobado hace unos minutos. Había sido un error del IDE en las pruebas anteriores...
Muchas gracias por molestarte!

Comment: @Fëanor, lo único por lo que podría dar problemas sería que tuvieras un método `toString()` personalizado en la clase dentro del cual hicieras alguna manipulación extraña o errónea, por eso era importante ver cómo estaba escrita la clase. Saludos.