# Crear un HASHMAP con una clase como parámetro

Tags: java

Me está dando un error de tipo `stackoverflow` a la hora de intentar crear un `hashmap` con una clase como parámetro. La declaración es la siguiente:

```
private Map <String, usuarios > usuarios = new HashMap<>();
```

`usuarios` es una clase de la que dispongo que contiene el siguiente constructor:

```
public usuarios(String usuario, String pass){
        this.usuario= usuario;
        this.pass = pass;                       
    }
```

El error en concreto me lo da en el momento de llenar el `map`:

```
usuarios.put("1" , new usuarios("maljonas", "1234"));
```

y es de tipo:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: La verdad es que en esos fragmentos de codigo no esta el error. Como recomendacion, nombra mejor tus variables y clases, tu clase probablemente deberia llamarse `Usuario` y no `usuarios`. Coloca el stacktrace completo en lugar de solo el mensaje.

Comment: Como ha dicho @Klaimmore, tu código, aunque viola gravemente el principio de la [Convención de nombres](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78423/29967), funciona, de modo que el error debería estar en otra parte. No obstante, considera diferenciar tus variables y aplicar correctamente la convención de nombres. En este caso estás escribiendo un código en extremo confuso, al llamar al `Map` exactamente como se llama la clase y al no usar mayúsculas para la 1ª letra de la clase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este código no funciona:

```
private Map <String, usuarios > usuarios = new HashMap<>();
```

El problema es que estás usando `usuarios` recursivamente y por eso arroja el error que mencionas.

Lo que quieres lograr es algo así:

```
    Map<String, Usuario> mapaDeUsuarios = new HashMap<>();
    mapaDeUsuarios.put("1", new Usuario("maljonas", "1234"));
    mapaDeUsuarios.put("2", new Usuario("lopez", "12345"));

    Usuario usuario2 = mapaDeUsuarios.get("2");
    System.out.println(usuario2.getUsuario());
```

Usar nombres más apropiados te va a ahorrar problemas. `Usuario` con inicial en mayúscula y en singular es tu clase que representa un sólo usuario. `mapaDeUsuarios` se explica sólo. También puedes nombrar tu mapa algo como: `posicionUsuario` para mencionar claramente que `posición` es la llave del mapa y `Usuario` contiene el objeto para la llave `posicion`.

Espero que esto te ayude.