# Al procesar todos los datos, me arroja que tiene errores. me podrían indicar que estoy haciendo mal

Tags: java, class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random; 
{ public class declaracion2
{
    public static void main (String args[])throws IOException 
    {                                       
        int x=6;
        float y=6;
        long z= 6;
        String M= "uno";
        char H= ´D´;
        Boolean= true;
        short r= 2;
        double w= 7.2;
        System.out.println(x);
    }   System.out.println(y);
        System.out.println(z);
        System.out.println(M);
        System.out.println(H);
        System.out.println("true");
        System.out.println(r);
        System.out.println(w);
```

Comment: Hay más errores en tu código: - Declarar `char H="D"` usando comillas ; -Dar un nombre a `Boolean bol= true;`. También conviene que respetes la convención de nombres en Java. Eso no es motivo de error, pero permite escribir un código que sea entendible para ti y para todos. Dicha convención no es observada en el nombre de la clase, ni en las variables `M` y `H`. [Puedes leer aquí sobre la *convención de nombres* en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78423/29967) para más detalles.

Answer (score 3):

Ricardo, la estructura de la clase esta mal en especial las posiciones de los corchetes `{}` la estructura es la siguiente:

```
import java.io.*

public class NombreClase{
  public static void main(String[] args){

    //aca todo el código    

  }// cierra metodo
}// cierra clase
```