# Problema con el uso de switch en android studio

Tags: android, activity

El problema en cuestión es que deseo configurar un switch para pasar de una activity a otra.
La cosa es que el programa compila normal pero a la hora de usar el switch me dice que que la aplicación se detuvo.

Codigo actual:

```
package com.exercisetosuityou.exercisetosuityou;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Switch;

public class Test_entrenamiento extends AppCompatActivity {
    Switch switchE;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_entrenamiento);
        switchE=(Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchEntrenamientoencasa);
    }

    public void Anterior(View view){
        Intent anterior=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(anterior);
    }



    public void Entrenamientoencasa(View view) {
        if(switchE.isChecked()){
        Intent entrenamientoencasa=new Intent(this,Entrenamientoencasa.class);
        startActivity(entrenamientoencasa);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Podrias aclararnos un poco más el error al que te refieres con `se detuvo`?

Comment: Qué es switch? un checkbox?

Comment: exacto un ejemplo del switch es prender el wifi del telefono y por cierto mi aplicacion se llama exercise to suit you y cuando habilito el switch me dice "exercise to suit you se detuvo"

Comment: Daniel revisa el `Logcat` y pon en la pregunta la traza completa del error. Ahí te dice con precisión que es lo que está fallando. También te recomendaría que respetes la [convención de nombres](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78423/29967), tanto en los nombres de métodos como de clases o de variables. Con todo respeto, tu convención de nombres es caótica y viola casi todas las normas.

Comment: Daniel, **existen múltiples razones por la cuales se detiene tu aplicación, debes revisar el LogCat como comenta A.Cedano** y agregar esa información a tu pregunta, de otra forma estaríamos tratando de adivinar, incluso el problema podría no estar en el "switch", saludos!

Answer (score -1):

veamos .. ya que no has copiado todo el codigo necesario .

verifica tu xml de Switch (ejemplo)

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Switch" />
```

importa

```
import android.widget.Switch;
```

declara la variable

```
Switch switch1= (Switch)findViewById(R.id.switch1);
```

ejecuta el evento

```
switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // muestra un activity
        } else {
            // muestra otro activity
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hola men tengo problemas con eso adjunto screenshot: https://gyazo.com/3cb012eebe36ef72a0f2c076f760bf74

Comment: cambia this por getApplicationContext()

Comment: en vez de this . pon.. el nombre de tu activity seguido de punto y el texto this .. ejemplo    actnombre.this