# Error con firebase y Android studio Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Tengo un erro que quisiera ver si me pueden ayudar,  lo que sucede es que en firebase ingrese un string largo manualmente el cual quiero que salga en mi aplicación
[image: Este es el string]

en mi codigo tengo lo siguiente para traer los datos de la base , el scrolltext .Stext es donde tengo que poner el string ya que si pongo manualmente si me sale

```
 db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            user = auth.getCurrentUser();
            usersRef = db.getReference("Cuentos" ).child("Cuento1");
            usersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for (DataSnapshot objetsnatshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                        Cuentos s1=dataSnapshot.getValue(Cuentos.class);
                        String stringcuento=s1.getHistory();


                        ScrollTextView scrolltext=(ScrollTextView) findViewById(R.id.scrolltext);
                        scrolltext.setText(stringcuento);
                        scrolltext.startScroll();



                    }
```

Tambien les pongo mi clase siendo history cuentos

```
public class Cuentos {
public String history,Nivel,Nombre;

public Cuentos(String historystring, String nivelcuento, String nombrecuento ) {
    this.history = historystring;
    this.Nivel = nivelcuento;
    this.Nombre = nombrecuento;


}

public Cuentos() {}

public String getHistory() {
    return history;
}

public void setHistory(String history) {
    this.history = history;
}
```

}

y el mensaje de error es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

YA INTENTE CAMBIAR A LONG Y VISEVERSA no se si me puedan ayudar a resolver esto y si se puede poner un long tan largo en firebase

Comment: Cuál es la línea donde te da el error? El error que salta es claro, no puedes asignar un Long a un String pero concreta la línea y lo podremos mirar.

Comment: El problema es la clave `Nivel`, es del tipo `Long`, pero en la clase la tienes declarada como `String`. Si la misma es `String`, debes escribir el valor así en Firebase: `"1"`. ¿El valor de la clave `Nombre` está escrito con o sin comillas al principio y al final?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es claro: *Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String*  quiere decir que se intenta convertir un valor del tipo `Long` a `String`.

Al mapear los datos a la clase `Cuento`, se encuentra que el valor `Nivel` es reconocido en Firebase como del tipo `Long` (porque el mismo no está escrito entre comillas), pero en la clase lo tienes declarado como `String`:

```
public String history,Nivel,Nombre;
```

### Soluciones

#### Uno (no recomendada si `Nivel` será siempre numérico)

Si el valor debe ser tratado como String, debes escribirlo en Firebase rodeado de comillas: **`"1"`**. Prestando estricta atención de que así sea **en todos los nodos**, pues en cualquier nodo que escribas el dato sin comillas te dará el error, porque en la clase está declarado como String.

#### Dos (recomendada si `Nivel` será siempre numérico)

Si el valor debe ser tratado como `Long`, o como `int`, tienes que declararlo como tal en la clase, y cambiar ese parámetro en el constructor, también en el *getter* y el *setter* si fuera preciso:

```
public class Cuentos {
    public String history,Nombre;
    /*Aquí es declarado como Long*/
    public Long Nivel;

    /*También en el constructor*/
    public Cuentos(String historystring, Long nivelcuento, String nombrecuento ) {
        this.history = historystring;
        this.Nivel = nivelcuento;
        this.Nombre = nombrecuento;
    }

    public Cuentos() {}

    public String getHistory() {
        return history;
    }

    public void setHistory(String history) {
        this.history = history;
    }

    /*También en el getter*/
    public Long getNivel() {
        return Nivel;
    }

    /*También en el setter*/
    public setNivel (Long Nivel) {
        this.Nivel=Nivel;
    }
}
```

> **NOTA:** Recomiendo que respetes [la convención de nombres en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78423/29967). He puesto tus variables como las tenías, pero las mismas son
>   incoherentes en cuanto a la convención de nombres. Esto no es motivo
>   de error, pero el código es menos claro y te dará problema si algún
>   día algún otro programador entra a trabajar en conjunto en tu
>   aplicación.