# ¿Como hago para hacer el promedio en el metodo : calcularPromedioPesoDescarga? POO Java

Tags: java, poo, método

tengo que hacer este programa , mi duda es como hacer el punto 4) , que es calcular el promedio de la clase Locomotora .Por el momento se me ocurrio hacer una sumatoria para pesoDeCarga que pertence a la clase vagon y otra sumatoria para cantidadDeVagones de la clase Locomotora : promedio = sumatoriaDePeso / sumatoriaDeCarga , pero en eclipse me da error, seguro lo estoy pensado mal , pero no se me ocurre de que otra manera hacerlo.

Se necesita generar las siguientes clases para una empresa ferroviaria :

1)Genera la clase Vagon con los siguientes atributos :

identificadorDeVagon : String

descripcion : String

marca : String

pesoMaximoQueSoporta : int

pesoDeCarga : int

Generar 2 constructores con las siguientes restricciones para la clase Vagon

a)Constructor que reciba todos los parametros de la clase vagon

b)Los campos identificadorDeVagon , marca y pesoMaximoQueSoporta son obligatorio

c)En caso que se omita el pesoDeCarga debe asignar el valor 0

d)De un ejemplo como usar ambos constructores

2)Crear la clase Locomotora con los siguientes atributos :

a)identificadorLocomotora : String

vagones[]: Vagon

b)Crear un constructor para la clase Locomotora que reciba los siguientes parametros (String identificacionLocomotora , int cantidadDeVagones)

3) Generar los siguientes metodos respetando las convenciones de JAVA

CLASE VAGON :

•getIdentificadorDeVagon

•setIdentificadorDeVagon

•getPesoDeCarga

•setPesoDeCarga

•toString

CLASE LOCOMOTORA :

•getVagones

•setVagones

4)Se debe crear el metodo calcularPromedioPesoDecarga clase Locomotora. Dicho metodo debe calcular el promedio de las cargas de todos los vagones .

5)Generar un metodo que verifique el formato del atributo identificadorDeVagon . El formato de dicho campo deben ser el primer caracter un caracter y el resto de los caracteres un entero . Ejemplo A12345 en caso que se cumpla dicha condicion el metodo debe devolver un true y por lo contratio un false.

```
public class Vagon {


//Atributos

private String identificadorDeVagon ;
private  String descripcion ;
private String marca ;
private int pesoMaximoQueSoporta ;
private int pesoDeCarga;

//Constructores

public Vagon (String identificadorDeVagon , String descripcion , String marca , int pesoMaximoQueSoporta , int pesoDeCarga ){
    this.identificadorDeVagon = identificadorDeVagon ;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.marca = marca;
    this.pesoMaximoQueSoporta = pesoMaximoQueSoporta ;
    this.pesoDeCarga = pesoDeCarga;

}

public Vagon (String identificadorDeVagon , String marca ,  int pesoMaximoQueSoporta) {

    this.identificadorDeVagon = identificadorDeVagon ;
    this.marca = marca;
    this.pesoMaximoQueSoporta = 0;

}

public String getidentificadorDeVagon () {

    return this.identificadorDeVagon;
}

public void setidentificadorDeVagon(String identificadorDeVagon) {

    this.identificadorDeVagon = identificadorDeVagon ;
}

public int getpesoDeCarga () {

    return this.pesoDeCarga;
}

public void setpesoDeCarga(int pesoDeCarga) {

    this.pesoDeCarga = pesoDeCarga;


}
```

public String toString() {
        return "Vagon [identificadorDeVagon=" + identificadorDeVagon + ", pesoDeCarga=" + pesoDeCarga + "]";
    }

public boolean identificadorDeVagon (char id) {

```
 boolean estado = false; 
 char unCaracter[] = new char[1];
 unCaracter [0] = 'A';
 int entero [] = new int[1];
 entero[0] = 12345;


 for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {



     if((id ==unCaracter[0])&&(id ==entero[0])) {

         estado = true;


     }

     else {

         estado = false;
     }
}


 return estado;
```

}
}

```
public class Locomotora {

//Atributos

    private String identificacionLocomotora ;
    private Vagon vagones[];

    //Constructor

    public Locomotora(String identificadorLocomotora , int cantidadDeVagones) {
        this.identificacionLocomotora = identificadorLocomotora;
        this.vagones = new Vagon [cantidadDeVagones];

    }


    public Vagon[] getvagones() {

        return this.vagones;

    }

    public void setVagones(Vagon[] vagones) {

        this.vagones = vagones ;
    }

    public double calcularPromedioPesoDescarga() {

        double promedio ;

        int sumatoriaPeso;
        int sumatoriaCarga;

        sumatoriaPeso += this.getpesoDeCarga;
        sumatoriaCarga+=this.vagones;

        promedio = sumatoriaPeso / sumatoriaCarga;

        return promedio;
    }
```

}

```
public class PruebaVagon {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //1)d)Ejemplos de como usar los dos contructores
     Vagon vagon1 = new Vagon ("678u" ,"azul" , "ffs" , 4576 ,234);
     Vagon vagonn = new Vagon ("htr780","lolop" , 87089);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que la clase `Locomotora` recibe un array de vagones, entonces es necesario abrir un bucle `for` para sumar el total de peso que soporta la locomotora, dividiendo luego ese total entre todos los vagones.

A partir de Java 8, en lugar del bucle `for` puedes usar expresiones lambda para hacer el cálculo.

El bucle `for` que usamos aquí usa elementos de la clase `Vagon`, por lo que podemos usar el método `getpesoDeCarga()` para obtener el peso de cada uno.

El método entonces quedaría así:

```
public double calcularPromedioPesoDescarga() {
    int sumatoriaPeso=0;
    int totalVagones=this.vagones.length;
    for (Vagon vagon: this.vagones) {  
        sumatoriaPeso+=vagon.getpesoDeCarga();
    }
    double promedioCarga=sumatoriaPeso/totalVagones;
    return promedioCarga;
}
```

En cuanto al código de prueba, si quieres lo puedes escribir así, para no tener que setear cada vagón por separado a la clase:

```
     Vagon[] vagones = new Vagon[2];
     vagones[0] = new Vagon ("678u" ,"azul" , "ffs" , 4576 ,234);
     vagones[1] = new Vagon ("htr780","lolop" ,87089);
     Locomotora biVagon=new Locomotora("loc1",2);
     biVagon.setVagones(vagones);
     System.out.println(biVagon.calcularPromedioPesoDescarga());
```

La salida, con los datos de prueba que muestras es la siguiente:

```
117.0
```

Ese es el peso promedio de tu locomotora de dos vagones.

> **NOTA:**
>
> Algunos de tus métodos no cumplen la [*convención de nombres*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78423/29967) de
>   Java. Por ejemplo este método: <s>`getpesoDeCarga()`</s>, debe ser
>   escrito así para que respete la convención de nombres:
>   **`getPesoDeCarga()`**.

Comment: Muchas Gracias :D... saludos!