# Ejercicio reloj en Java

Tags: java

Soy un novato en esto de java y acabo de empezar las clases, nos han mandado este ejercicio:

Ejercicio 3

1. Diseñar una clase llamada `Reloj` con los atributos enteros: `hora` (24 horas), `minuto` y `segundo`, y los métodos siguientes:
2. Un constructor que inicialice los atributos a valores pasados como parámetros.
3. Un método llamado Incrementa que incremente la hora en un segundo.

Por ejemplo:

`17:53:59` será `17:54:00`

`17:59:59` será `18:00:00`

4.Un método llamado Decrementa que disminuya la hora en un segundo.

Por ejemplo:

`17:53:00` será `17:52:59`

`17:00:00` será `16:59:59`

5.Un método llamado `Hora12` que convierte a `String` la hora mediante la concatenación de sus atributos y devuelve la cadena con el formato de 12 horas (`hh:mm:ss AM/PM`)

AM: (hasta las 12 mediodía), PM (desde las 12 hasta las 24 horas)

Este es mi código, Clase `Reloj`:

```
public class Reloj {
    int modo,hora, minutos,segundos;

    int getmodo(){

    return modo;

    }


    public void setmodo(int modo){

    this.modo=modo;
    }

    int gethora(){

    return hora;

    }


    public void sethora(int hora){

    this.hora=hora;
    }

    public int getminutos(){

    return minutos;

    }


    public void setminutos(int minutos){

    this.minutos=minutos;
    }

    public  int getsegundos(){

    return segundos;

    }


   public  void setsegundos(int segundos){

    this.segundos=segundos;
    }

   public  Reloj(){
    modo=24; /*por defecto ponemos 24horas*/
    hora=0;
    minutos=0;
    segundos=0;


    }

    public Reloj( int h, int m, int s){
        this.modo=24;
        this.hora=h %24;
        this.minutos=m % 60;
        this.segundos=s % 60;

    }


   public void ponerEnHora(int md, int hh, int mm, int ss){
      modo=md;
      hora=hh % 24;
      minutos=mm % 60;
      segundos=ss % 60;
   }

   public void incrementar(){
    segundos++;
    if (segundos==60){
    segundos=0;
    minutos++;
    if(minutos==60){
    minutos=0;
    hora=(hora+1)%24;
    }

    }

    }

   public void decrementa(){
    segundos--;
    if(segundos<00){
        segundos=59;
        minutos--;
        if(minutos<00){
        minutos=59;
        hora=(hora-1) %24;

        }
    }
   }
   public String verHora(){

       String hms="Son las ";

       if (modo==12){//modo 12 horas    
           hms+=(hora>12)?hora-12:hora;
           hms+= ":"+minutos+":"+segundos;
           hms+=(hora>=12)?"pm":"am";

       }else{//modo 24h
       hms+=hora+":"+minutos+":"+segundos;
       }
   return (hms);
   }
}
```

Clase relojes MAIN:

```
public class Relojes {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Reloj reloj1 = new Reloj();
        reloj1.ponerEnHora(24,17,10,10);
        System.out.println(reloj1.verHora());
        reloj1.incrementar();
        System.out.println(reloj1.verHora());
        reloj1.decrementa();
        System.out.println(reloj1.verHora());

    }

}
```

No me sale las horas en modo 12H, todo lo demás funciona, pero que me imprima el modo 12h con AM o PM no me sale, a ver si me podéis echar una mano.

Comment: En ningún momento le indicas que el `modo` sea 12 por lo que es imposible que te lo muestre.

Comment: En el main tendrias que llamar setModo(12) para pasar al modo de 12 hs.

Comment: Gracias Juan, era eso!

Comment: @Flowcou Buena primera pregunta: clara y completa, con todo lo necesario para que entandamos el problema. Puedes autorresponderte y señalar la respuesta como aceptada para *cerrar* la pregunta (que quede marcada como respondida) si así lo deseas.

Comment: Simplemente quiero hacer notar que muchos de tus métodos no usan la [*convención de nombres*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78423/29967) recomendada por Java. Esto, aunque no influye en el funcionamiento del código, no ayuda a su comprensión y puede ser muy negativo si más adelante tu código tiene que formar parte de alguna biblioteca o de un proyecto donde se trabajará en equipo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

solo faltaba llamar al metodo setModo de la clase Reloj y darle las 12

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Reloj reloj1 = new Reloj();        
    reloj1.ponerEnHora(24,17,10,10);

    reloj1.setmodo(12);//cambiamos el modo por defecto de 24 a 12

    System.out.println(reloj1.verHora());
    reloj1.incrementar();
    System.out.println(reloj1.verHora());
    reloj1.decrementa();
    System.out.println(reloj1.verHora());

}
```