# ¿Para qué sirve el this.hora = h % 24; en Java?

Tags: java, netbeans, operador-resto-division

Hola soy nuevo en Java y no sé para que sirve el *n % 24* antes de un número, quería salir de duda si es un número máximo que al momento de ingresar un dato no supere al 24, ya que en una pregunta mire este código:

```
public Reloj(int h, int m, int s) {
    this.modo = 24;
    this.hora = h % 24;
    this.minutos = m % 60;
    this.segundos = s % 60;
}
```

Este es el enlace donde encontré esto:
[Ejercicio reloj en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/217373/ejercicio-reloj-en-java#comment404447_217373)

Les agradecería mucho que me explicaran para que sirve, o que me compartieran enlaces de su funcionamiento.

Comment: No sirve para establecer un máximo pero si se puede limitar un número a un rango de una forma particular (explicada en la respuesta). Por ejemplo `n % 24` hará que el número esté entre 0 y 23.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El **operador %** es el **resto de la división**, ejemplo, **5 % 2** deja un resto de **1**, **las divisiones no exactas dejan un resto r > 0** y **las divisiones exactas dejan un resto r = 0**.

Ahora bien en el ejercicio que analizas que es un reloj el **operador %** se usa para volver al valor inicial y empezar todo de nuevo, tomemos como ejemplo las horas, como sabrás **un día tiene 24 horas**, si empezamos en la **hora** **0** por ejemplo **0 % 24 = 0**; **1 % 24 = 1**; ... ; **23 % 24 = 23**; **24 % 24 = 0** y se reinicia el valor de las horas y todo vuelve a comenzar y se repite una y otra vez, lo mismo pasa por supuesto con los minutos y segundos pero esta vez es **% 60**.