# ¿Cómo cambiar el resultado de un String?

Tags: java, firebase

En mi código tengo un elemento String asunto_pago = "";

Quiero hacer que dependiendo al resultado de un lector de código QR ese elemento String se llene con una palabra. Ejemplo:

```
if (saldo.getText().toString().contentEquals(saldo_minimo)){
                            goanimationnomoney();
                            String asunto_pago = "Cigarro";
                        }
```

El anterior es el codigo que tengo pero no funciona. Espero alguien me diga que esta mal en mi codigo.

La idea es llenar el elemento String asunto_pago = "";

con la palagra "Cigarro"

para que cuanto se capture para enviar a una base de datos se capture la palabra Cigarro

Comment: Te recomiendo que antes de pensar en aplicaciones, bases de datos, etc., te revises un manual de programación para aprender sobre qué son las variables y cuál es su ámbito según donde las definas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeramente, para poder usar el objeto `asunto_pago` en otro ámbito, tienes que declararlo fuera del bloque `if`, pues al declararlo dentro no podrás usarlo luego fuera de ese ámbito. Otra posibilidad sería pasarlo desde dentro del bloque `if` al otro ámbito donde vas a usar `asunto_pago`.

Luego, para esta comparación no necesitas usar `contentEquals`, basta con usar `equals`. Para comprender la diferencia entre ambos, puedes leer las respuestas a la pregunta [*Difference between String#equals and String#contentEquals methods*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6476600/5587982)

Tu código podría quedar así:

```
//Se crea el objeto y se inicializa con un valor en blanco
String asunto_pago = "";

if (saldo.getText().toString().equals(saldo_minimo)){
    //Aquí sólo asignas el valor Cigarro al objeto previamente declarado
    asunto_pago="Cigarro";
    goanimationnomoney();
}

//Aquí otro contexto donde se usará asunto_pago con el valor que tenga
```

En cambio, si el objeto se usa únicamente en el método `goanimationnomoney` podrías modificar ese método, haciendo que reciba el objeto  `asunto_pago` en parámetro y pasarlo en la llamada.

La signatura del método sería entonces así (los ... deben ser cambiados por el tipo de método, indicar si es void o no o indicar el tipo de dato que devolvería):

```
... goanimationnomoney (String asunto_pago) {
    //Usar asunto_pago
}
```

Y, desde dentro del bloque `if`:

```
if (saldo.getText().toString().equals(saldo_minimo)){
    //Aquí no hace falta guardar el dato, lo pasas directamente
    goanimationnomoney("Cigarro");
}
```

Nótese que aquí pasas el dato directamente al método. Esto se justificaría en un escenario en el que sólo necesites ese dato para usarlo en el método `goanimationnomoney()`.

Como recomendación final, considera usar una *convención de nombre* adecuada. En Java, los métodos tienen una convención de nombre que consiste en poner la primera palabra en minúscula y luego dentro, cada inicio de palabra distinta en mayúscula. Aplicando eso, tu método debería llamarse: `goAnimationNoMoney()`. [En esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78423/29967) se explica de forma sencilla y con ejemplos cómo aplicar una convención de nombre adecuada en Java. Llamar a tu método `goanimationnomoney` no provocará errores en el código, pero no se ajusta a ninguna *convención de nombre* habitual.