# imprimir una variable devuelta por un metodo (java)

Tags: java

He creado una clase de objeto llamada "Ficha" con 3 variables de tipo String. Luego he creado un método para ingresar los valores de esas variables. Y quiero imprimir uno de esos valores en el Main. Pero cuando compilo me dice que no encuentra el símbolo (la variable que quiero imprimir)(en la última línea del código). Cómo debo imprimir?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Pswd {

  static class Ficha {
    String Servicio;
    String Usuario;
    String Contrasena;
  }

  static Ficha CrearFicha () {

    Ficha myObj= new Ficha();

    Scanner myInp = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingresa servicio");
    myObj.Servicio = myInp.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Ingresa Usuario");
    myObj.Usuario = myInp.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Ingresa Contrasena");
    myObj.Contrasena = myInp.nextLine();

    return myObj;
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    CrearFicha();
    System.out.println(myObj.Servicio); //a ésta línea apunta el error

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma mas sencilla es esta, porque ya en tu método `crearFicha()` estas instanciando la clase, por lo que es innecesario volver a instaciar en el Main

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
      System.out.println(CrearFicha().Servicio);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Según la lógica de tu programa `CrearFicha()` retorna un objeto el tipo `Ficha`, pero no lo estás recogiendo en el  `main`.

Puedes hacerlo así simplemente:

```
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Ficha mFicha=CrearFicha();
    System.out.println(mFicha.Servicio); //a ésta línea apunta el error

  }
```

**PD:** Hago notar que no estás usando la *convención de nombre* recomendada para Java. Los nombres de métodos deberían tener la primera palabra en minúscula (`crearFicha()`), así como los nombres de variable (`servicio`). Mientras que los nombres de clase cada primera palabra en mayúscula. Para más detalles consulta esta pregunta: *[¿Cuál es la convención para escribir variables en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/78420/29967)*