# Modificar variables de otra clase con Scanner

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de java en el que tengo que declarar unas variables en una clase y luego en otra clase que el usuario debe definirlas, de momento esto es lo que tengo hecho

```
public  class persona  
{ 
        public String nombre; //Declaramos las variable que vamos a usar
        public String apellido;
        public int edad;
    public void persona()
    {
        
        
        
    }   
}
```

y esto es lo de la segunda clase:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class principal
{
    
    public static void main()
    {
        persona nombre = new persona(); //declaramos las variables de la otra clase
        persona apellido = new persona();
        persona edad = new persona(); 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //declaramos el scanner
        
        
        System.out.println("Introduce nombre"); // pedimos al usuario que introduzca los datos
         nombre = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Introduce apellido");
         apellido = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Introduce edad");
         edad = sc.nextInt();
        
        //los mostramos por pantalla
        System.out.println("Los datos de la persona introducida son: Nombre: "+ nombre + "\n Apellido: " + apellido + "\n Edad: " + edad );
    }

    
}
```

El problema que tengo es que los scanners me dan error, he probado hacer más de un scanner pero no he conseguido nada

Comment: El problema no lo tienes con el Scanner, lo tienes con entender lo que es un objeto. Una clase es una definición, una plantilla con la que crear objetos y cada objeto creado tendrá las variables definidas en la clase. No tienes que crear un objeto para cada variable de la clase, sino un objeto persona solamente y a las variables de ese objeto es a las que les das valor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu código está mal planteado del todo. Vamos por partes:

En primer lugar tú estás confundiendo *instancia* de una clase con *miembros* o *campos* de una clase. La clase es `persona` y tiene tres campos: `nombre, apellido, edad`. Pero tú estás creando **tres instancias** de la clase, una para cada miembro:

```
persona nombre = new persona(); //declaramos las variables de la otra clase
persona apellido = new persona();
persona edad = new persona();
```

En ese código, `nombre` sería una `persona`, `apellido` otra `persona` y `edad` otra `persona`.

Con algo como esto puedes instanciar una `persona` (a la cual luego le asignarás sus campos cuando veamos el diseño de la clase):

```
Persona personOne = new Persona(); //personeOne es una instancia de la clase Persona
```

En segundo lugar, tu clase `Persona` no está completa. Necesitaría al menos unos métodos para setear las propiedades y otros para obtenerlas. No es obligatorio que así sea, tú puedes inicializar los miembros de la clase también desde el constructor, pero para informar una clase desde un `Scanner` es mejor usar los *setter* porque cada información se va proporcionando por separado. También, se recomienda que los miembros de la clase sean `private` para que no puedan ser modificados directamente, pero no nos metamos ahora en eso. Veamos un ejemplo mínimo de la clase funcional para este caso. Voy a escribir el nombre de la clase usando `P` mayúscula, porque así lo pide la [*convención de nombre* en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78423/29967).

```
public  class Persona  
{ 
        private String nombre; //Declaramos las variable que vamos a usar
        private String apellido;
        private int edad;

    public void setNombre(String nombre)
    {        
        this.nombre=nombre;
    }   

    public void setApellido(String apellido)
    {        
        this.apellido=apellido;
    }   

    public void setEdad(int edad)
    {        
        this.edad=edad;
    }   

    public String getNombre()
    {        
        return this.nombre;
    }   

    public String getApellido()
    {        
        return this.apellido;
    }   

    public int getEdad()
    {        
        return this.edad;
    }   
}
```

Ya tenemos una clase `Persona` funcional. Ahora vamos a usarla:

```
public static void main()
{
    Persona personOne = new Persona(); //Creamos una instancia de la clase
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //declaramos el scanner
    
    //Observa que en todo usaremos personOne en lo adelante
    System.out.println("Introduce nombre"); // pedimos al usuario que introduzca los datos
    //Usamos los setter de Persona para asignarle cada campo
    personOne.setNombre(sc.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Introduce apellido");
    personOne.setApellido(sc.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Introduce edad");
    personOne.setEdad(sc.nextInt());
    
    //los mostramos por pantalla
    //Aquí usamos los getter
    System.out.println("Los datos de la persona introducida son: Nombre: "+ personOne.getNombre() + "\n Apellido: " + personOne.getApellido() + "\n Edad: " + personOne.getEdad() );
}

}
```