# Imprimir array desde metodo?

Tags: java

Y no me sale…, mi intención era dentro de la clase plantilla, generar unos cuantos atributos, llevarlos a los valores principales declarados en los main values, con `this`. Y después convertirlos a una array para imprimir esta entera desde método, pero en algo debo estar fallando...

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
            perro perrete1 = new perro("wow", "18", "25");
            perrete1.getdogdata();
```

Aquí la clase

```
package ejemploss;

import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 *
 * @author alvar
 */
public class perro {

    public String name;
    public String edad;
    public String velocidad;
    public String datos[] = {name, edad, velocidad};
   

    public perro(String name, String edad, String velocidad) {
        this.name = name;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.velocidad = velocidad;
      
       
    }
    


    public void getdogdata() {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(datos));
        
        
       }

}
```

Gracias

Comment: La clase `perro` no está recibiendo nada para la propiedad `datos` debes pasarlo/asignarlo sea en el constructor o crear un *setter* para ello. Y considera usar bien la [*convención de nombre*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78423/29967). Los nombres de clase deben ir en PascalCase, por ejemplo `Perro` y los métodos con la primera letra en minúscula y luego primeras letras de cada palabra en mayúscula, por ejemplo: `getDogData()`, aunque generalmente los *getter* se escriben con el nombre de la propiedad, si es `datos`, sería: `getDatos()`

Comment: No he terminado de enteder tu respuesta.  Aunque declare:                                         public perro(String name, String edad, String velocidad) {
        this.name = name;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.velocidad = velocidad;
        String datos[] = {name, edad, velocidad};
       
    }
     Puedes porfavor, ponerme el ejemplo?

Comment: O, si sólo quieres imprimir las propiedades de la clase como array, puedes hacerlo, pero en el mismo método: `public void getdogdata() { String datos[] = {name, edad, velocidad}; System.out.println(Arrays.toString(datos)); }` El problema es que ahora mismo defines `datos` como una propiedad más de la clase, pero esa propiedad no es informada de ningún modo (como ocurre con `nombre` y las otras propiedades que sí son llenadas en el constructor. No sé si me explico.

Answer (score 3):

Si sólo quieres imprimir los datos del perro te recomendaría sobrescribir el método [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) y cambiar un poco tus variables.

El método [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) hereda de la clase [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), objeto del cual heredan **TODOS** los objetos en Java. Afortunadamente nosotros podemos [sobrescribir](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) este método de la siguiente forma:

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
    /* Tu método va aquí */
}
```

Entonces puedes usarlo en este caso. Además te recomiendo cambiar tus variables edad y velocidad a [otros tipos de datos primitivos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), específicamente byte y float. Te ayudarán a manejar mejor los datos de tu perrito.

- byte: tiene un rango incluyente de [-128, 127]. Recomiendo este tipo de dato pues ocupa menos espacio que un int y mucho menos que un String, además de que un perro no llega a tener tantos años.
- float: tiene una precisión de acuerdo a 32-bit IEEE 754. Recomiendo este tipo de dato pues te permite tener números flotantes de menos precisión y por tanto, menos espacio de memoria que un double.

El resultado sería algo parecido a esto:

**Clase Dog.java**

```java
public class Dog {

    public String name;
    public byte age;
    public float speed;


    public Dog(String name, byte age, float speed) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Nombre: " + name + ", Edad: " + age + ", Velocidad: " + speed;
    }

}
```

**Clase Main.java**

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog dog = new Dog("Firulais", (byte) 5, (float) 25.2);
        System.out.println(dog.toString());
    }

}
```

**Resultado de la ejecución**

```
Nombre: Firulais, Edad: 5, Velocidad: 25.2
```

**Sobre tu problema**

¿Por qué tu método no imprimía los datos que tú querías?

Sigue esta lógica:

1. Se declaran tus variables: `name`, `edad` y `velocidad` las cuales están inicializadas en `null`
2. Se declara tu variable `datos` y se le asignan los valores `name`, `edad` y `velocidad`, que recordarás que son `null`
3. Imprimes tus datos pero estos son nulos, pues nunca actualizaste tu variable `datos`

Entonces el **resultado esperado** es:

```
[null, null, null]
```

Answer (score 2):

En tu clase, `datos` ha sido declarada como una propiedad más, en la cabecera de la clase, junto a las demás propiedades:

```
public String name;
public String edad;
public String velocidad;
public String datos[] = {name, edad, velocidad};
```

Todas las propiedades que son definidas ahí, tienen que ser pasadas a la instancia de la clase, sea en el constructor, sea por otra vía.

Si observamos el constructor:

```
public perro(String name, String edad, String velocidad) {
    this.name = name;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.velocidad = velocidad;   
}
```

Estás pasando `name`, `edad` y `velocidad` ... pero ¿y `datos` que definiste  también como propiedad de la clase?

Dado que la intención es crear una especie de método `toString()` a tu manera, podrías hacer algo así:

**Primero:** quitar la definición de datos en la cabecera de la clase:

```
//public String datos[] = {name, edad, velocidad};
```

**Segundo:** crear el array dentro del método:

```
public void getdogdata() {
    String datos[] = {name, edad, velocidad};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(datos));
}
```

Aquí no habrá ningún problema, porque `datos` se define en el ámbito del método y `datos` no es otra cosa que un array basado en propiedades de la clase que ya pusiste en contexto en el constructor.

Puedes hacer también esto simplemente, lo cual demuestra que **una propiedad `datos` no es necesaria como tal**:

```
public void getdogdata() {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new String[]{name, edad, velocidad}));
}
```

En realidad, **`datos` es un objeto utilitario, pero tú lo estabas concibiendo como una propiedad de la clase que contenía otras propiedades** ... lo cual no tiene ningún sentido.

Lo que es preciso entender es que **todas las propiedades de tu clase deben recibir un valor de algún modo**. Y que para el uso que quieres darle a `datos`, este objeto **no debe ser declarado como una propiedad de la clase**, porque no lo es realmente.

Ten cuidado con estas confusiones, que te pueden llevar a escribir diseños pésimos de clases. Piensa las clases de entidades (`Perro` lo es) desde un punto de vista metafísico: sólo debes definir como propiedades de la misma **aquello que es intrínsecamente propio del *ser* `Perro`** (`name, edad, velocidad`). Un perro no tiene nada que se llame `datos`, eso es algo circunstancial por decirlo de algún modo, no es parte de la definición metafísica de `Perro`.

Comment: En todo caso si sólo quiere imprimir los datos del Perro, sería mejor sobrescribir el método `toString()`, ¿no?

Comment: @EduardoJiménez correcto, la práctica habitual es dotar a la clase de su propio método `toString()`