# ¿Cómo puedo llamar a otra clase dentro del mismo paquete?

Tags: java

Corregí el código, me había confundido al llamar la clase secundaria, pero no me reconoce la clase, el código si me funciona cuando no agrego el "package", pero aquí quiero usarlo con el package y me lanza ese error.

```
package paquete1;

public class secundaria{
    public void metodo(){
        System.out.print("Hola Mundo");
    }
}
```

```
package paquete1;

public class primaria{
    public static void main(String[] args){
      secundaria s= new secundaria();
      s.metodo();
    }
}
```

```
    primaria.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
      secundaria s= new secundaria();
      ^
  symbol:   class secundaria
  location: class primaria
primaria.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
      secundaria s= new secundaria();
                        ^
  symbol:   class secundaria
  location: class primaria
2 errors
```

Comment: La clase se llama `secundaria`, no se llama `metodo` y tiene un `metodo()`, no se llama `metodo1()`. Intenta así: **`secundaria s=new secundaria(); s.metodo();`** Y, dado que estás empezando, te aconsejo que consideres aplicar la [*convención de nombres* propia de Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78423/29967) en tus programas.

Comment: Cuando instancias una clase, se instancia el nombre de la clase no de los métodos

Comment: Es muy extraño lo que dices. ¿Ambas clases están en el mismo `package`? ¿Podrías mostrar una captura del árbol de paquetes de tu proyecto?

Answer (score 4):

La clase se llama **`secundaria`**, no se llama `metodo` y el método se llama **`metodo()`**, no se llama `metodo1()`, ni la clase tiene un método llamado `metodo1()`.

Intenta así:

```
secundaria s=new secundaria(); 
s.metodo();
```

Parece que hay una confusión sobre cómo se crean las instancias de objeto en Java. Las instancias se crean indicando primero el tipo, luego cómo se llamará esa instancia en ese contexto y luego invocando el constructor.

O sea:

```
Tipo nombreEnContexto = new Tipo([parametros si los hay]);
```

Imagina que quieres dos instancias de la clase `secundaria`:

```
    secundaria secondOne =     new secundaria(); 

/*    ^ tipo   ^nombre         ^constructor
                en contexto
*/

    secundaria secondTwo =     new secundaria(); 

/*    ^ tipo   ^nombre         ^constructor
                en contexto
*/
```

Siempre pones a la izquiera el tipo (nombre de la clase), luego un nombre que diferencie a cada instancia, así, `secondOne` y `secondTwo` son dos instancias de tu clase `secundaria`, pero para llamar a sus métodos, la llamada será siempre igual:

```
secondOne.metodo();
secondTwo.metodo();
```

Si tuvieras que usar `metodo1()` para llamar al método de la primera instancia y `metodo2()` para llamar al método de la segunda instancia, sería una locura.

Todo en Java es un objeto. Por ejemplo, para crear una cadena haces esto:

```
      String mName      =      "Oscar";

/*    ^ tipo   ^nombre         ^constructor ¿?
                en contexto
*/
```

Aquí el constructor no es necesario, dado que los objetos de la [clase `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(java.lang.String)) son inmutables. .

OJO: Esto NO es lo mismo (internamente) que hacer esto:

```
String mName = new String ("Oscar");
```

Aquí se llama a [un método concreto de la clase `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String))  y se crean dos instancias de la clase `String`, primero la del parámetro, la cual finalmente es copiada al resultado de la llamada del constructor (`mName`). Por eso nunca verás crear instancias de String usando el constructor, sino directamente ([ver esta pregunta para más detalles sobre esto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3052442/5587982)).

Creo que ayuda mucho pensar siempre que en Java todo es un objeto. Observa esto mismo que tienes en tu método:

```
    System.out.print("Hola Mundo");
```

Es una llamada al [método `print()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(boolean))  del objeto `PrintStream` (`out`) que es parte de la clase `System`. Imagina que Java estuviese diseñado de modo que tengas que poner un número delante cada vez que debas llamar al método `print` ... sería una locura.

Otra cosa que ayuda mucho, sobre todo al inicio, es no olvidar que la POO ha sido pensada para acercar la programación a la realidad. Por ejemplo, los métodos deben llevar siempre nombres de verbos, porque sirven para ejecutar acciones: *imprimir, reservar, comparar, hablar, comer ...* En la vida tú imprimes, reservas, hablas, comes miles o millones de veces, pero siempre invocas a los métodos sin importar cuántas veces hayas reservado o comido o hablado. Dicho de otro modo: sin importar las veces que deba hacerse, ni la cantidad de **instancias** de ese objeto que deban hacerlo, siempre se usará **ese método** que existe en el objeto precisamente para realizar **esa** acción específica.

Cuando vas a *comer* haces esto:

```
Persona yoDeAhora = new Persona();
yoDeAhora.comer();
```

Y cuando tu hermana va a *comer* haces esto:

```
Persona mSister = new Persona();
mSister.comer();
```

Podemos decir que `yoDeAhora` y `mSister` son dos `Personas` y que ambas han comido.

### Recomendación

Dado que estás empezando, te aconsejo que consideres aplicar la [*convención de nombres* propia de Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78423/29967) en tus programas.

Answer (score -1):

Intenta compilar la clase primaria con javac

1. ubícate fuera del paquete

   ```
   cd ..
   ```
2. Una vez fuera del paquete intenta

   ```
   javac paquete1\primaria.java
   ```