# Error a la hora de importar clases en proyecto Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Tengo un error que me causa curiosidad a la hora de querer usar el método **println**.

Tengo un proyecto Maven de prueba:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código de la clase **registrarProducto** (incompleto)

```
package org.example.Inventario;

public class registrarProducto {
    System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del producto: ")

}
```

Que me causa el error `Cannot resolve symbol 'println'`
Me da curiosidad el hecho que me de este error si en la clase App puedo usarlo correctamente sin ningún problema:

```
package org.example;

public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println("Texto de prueba");

    }

}
```

Mi pregunta es...¿por qué pasa este tipo de errores? leí que podría ser por el parámetro `String[] args` pero de igual manera al momento de querer usar el atajo **sout** en intellij da un menú con las clases o métodos que podemos usar en este caso `System.out.println();` en mi clase **App**, pero ni este atajo ni aún importando las clases en mi package **Inventario** puedo usar. ¿Hay alguna razón concreta de estos errores? si me podrían explicar el porqué se los agradecería, siempre tuve que tomar atajos para evitar estos errores pero quiero saber la razón para corregirlo siempre que pueda pasar. Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola, ¿puedes añadir el código completo de tu clase? En ese código el println no está dentro de ningún método... 

Por otro lado... te recomendaría visitar las code conventions de Java: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

El nombre de las clases debería empezar siempre en Mayúscula.

Comment: En la misma línea de lo que te dice @kasas12, ¿acaso `registrarProducto` no debería ser **un método de la clase `Producto`** y no una clase aparte? La [*convención de nombre*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78423/29967), que parece una tontería, no lo es, más bien te ayuda no sólo a escribir programas claros, sino a entender los principios de la POO. Por ejemplo, los verbos (registrar, guardar, etc) son por lo general métodos, los sustantivos (Producto, Persona, Empleado) son por lo general clases.

Comment: Se agradece las aportaciones, pasa que estoy aplicando SOLID y me he estado perdiendo un poco más que todo con el primer principio