# Rellenar un Array con datos de una variable[JAVA]

Tags: java

Me gustaría rellenar el array "movimiento" con todos los ingresos y retiradas de efectivo(máximo 10), cada vez que se haga un ingreso o un retiro de dinero que se guarde dentro del array pero no se me printea, sé que está mal, alguien me podría recomendar que poder hacer para conseguir lo que quiero?

```
public class CuentaBancaria {

private String iban, titular;
private double saldo;
private double[] movimiento = new double[10];

CuentaBancaria() {
    this.iban = "ES6621000418401234567891";
    this.saldo = 0.00;
}

// getter y setter

public String getiban() {
    return iban;
}

public String gettitular() {
    return titular;
}

public double getsaldo() {
    if (saldo < 0) {
        System.out.println("[AVISO] SALDO NEGATIVO");
    }
    return saldo;
}

public void setiban(String iban) {
    this.iban = iban;
}

public void settitular(String titular) {
    this.titular = titular;
}

public void setsaldo(Double saldo) {
    this.saldo = saldo;
}

public void ingreso(Double cantidad) {

    if (cantidad > 3000.00) {
        System.out.println("\n[AVISO] Se notificará a hacienda");
    }

    System.out.println("Ha ingresado " + cantidad + " Euros.");

    saldo = saldo + cantidad;
    // ingresar la cantidad en el vector
}

public void retirada(Double cantidad) {

    if (cantidad > 3000.00) {
        System.out.println("\n[AVISO] Se notificará a hacienda");
    }

    if (saldo > 50) {
        saldo = saldo - cantidad;
        System.out.println("Ha retirado " + cantidad + " Euros.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("[ERROR] INGRESE DINERO");
    }

}

public void movimientoingreso(Double cantidad) {

    for (int i = 0; i < movimiento.length; i++) {
        movimiento[i] = cantidad;
    }
}

public void movimientos() {

    for (int i = 0; i < movimiento.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(movimiento[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema aquí es que al ser `movimiento` un array de objetos primitivos, tienes que saber de antemano la posición en la que quieres colocar cada valor.

Esto se podría lograr fácilmente teniendo una propiedad de la clase que vaya controlando la cantidad de movimientos, y usarías esa propiedad, tanto para decidir si no se ha agotado el límite de transacciones, como para registrar la eventual transacción en ese índice.

También, esto ayudará a decidir sobre una laguna que no viene expresada en tu código de ningún modo: **¿los intentos fallidos cuentan como transacciones o no?**.

Otra cosa no controlada en tu código son los retiros. Tal y como tienes diseñada tu clase, a condición de tener más de 50 euros ¡puedo retirar 2,999 euros! ¡¡¡ El primero que irá a la cárcel será el programador !!!

He añadido otras mejoras en tu clase, pues conviene tener un código limpio, usando por ejemplo métodos para las verificaciones.

También, parece que estabas intentando dos métodos para ingreso.

He puesto comentarios en varias partes del código que pueden serte útiles.

La clase quedaría así:

```
public class CuentaBancaria {
     private String iban, titular;
     private double saldo;
     private double[] movimiento = new double[10];
     /*
         Control de movimientos
         cuando sea igual a 10 no permitirá más
         y evitará usar bucles para cada nuevo movimiento
         */
     private int countIndex=0;
     
     /*
         Establecerá el límite de movimientos
         10, según lo expuesto en la pregunta
         */
     private int dailyLimit=10;
     
     CuentaBancaria() {
         this.iban = "ES6621000418401234567891";
         this.saldo = 0.00;
     }

    // getter y setter
     public String getiban() {
         return iban;
     }
     
     public String gettitular() {
         return titular;
     }
     
     public double getsaldo() {
         if (saldo < 0) {
             System.out.println("\n[AVISO] SALDO NEGATIVO");
         }
         return saldo;
     }

    public void setiban(String iban) {
        this.iban = iban;
    }

    public void settitular(String titular) {
        this.titular = titular;
    }

    public void setsaldo(Double saldo) {
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }

    public void ingreso(Double cantidad) {
        /*
            Verificamos dos cosas:
                1. Si cantidad es legal (no excede 3,000)
                2. Si todavía le quedan transacciones
                Usaremos métodos dedicados, porque se necesitarán
                también para retirar
             Si la condición no se cumple, no cuenta como una 
            transacción, por eso no se aumenta a countIndex
            si debe ser de otro modo, debes decidirlo tú               
                */
        if (isLegal(cantidad)) {
            movimiento[countIndex]=cantidad;
            saldo = (saldo +  cantidad);
            countIndex++;
            showSuccessInfo(1,cantidad);
        }
    }
     
    /*
        Antes de retirar verificaremos dos cosas:
            1. Si no ha excedido la cuota de movimientos
            2. Si tiene fondos... Cada uno con su método
               Es importante centralizar ciertas operaciones en métodos
               primero, porque los puedes necesitar en otras partes
               segundo, porque el código queda más limpo
            Si la condición no se cumple, no cuenta como una 
            transacción, por eso no se aumenta a countIndex
            si debe ser de otro modo, debes decidirlo tú
               */

    public void retiro(Double cantidad) {   
        if (isLegal(cantidad) && hasFunds(cantidad)) {
            movimiento[countIndex]=cantidad;            
            saldo = (saldo - cantidad);
            countIndex++;
            showSuccessInfo(2,cantidad);          
        }
    }


    public void movimientos() {
        System.out.println("\n\nMOVIMIENTOS:\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < movimiento.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(movimiento[i]);
        }
    }
     
     /*
         Este método sirve para verificar si no ha excedido
         la cuota de movimientos. 
         Se usará desde ingreso() y desde retiro()
         Si no tiene cuota lo advertirá en un mensaje
         */
     private boolean hasQuota(){
         boolean hasQuota=(countIndex!=dailyLimit) ? true : false;
         if(!hasQuota) {
             showLimitInfo();
         }
         return hasQuota;
     }
     
     /*
         Este método determinará si la operación
         de ingreso/retiro es legal. 
         Es decir, si no excede la cantidad de 3000
         Si es ilegal, imprimirá un mensaje advirtiéndolo.
         Si es legal, verificará también si tiene cuota
         para hacer transacciones.
         La verificación de la cuota se ha centralizado aquí
         y aunque no tenga cuota, se advertirá sobre hacienda
         Si no debe advertirse, puedes invertir los if
         verificando primero si tiene cuota
         */
     private boolean isLegal(Double cantidad){
         boolean isLegal=true;
         if(cantidad > 3000.00) {
             isLegal=false;
             showIllegalInfo();
         }else{
             return hasQuota();                     
         }
         return isLegal;
     }     
     
     /*
         Este método verifica si tiene fondos
             1. Según tu código original, si el saldo
                es menor de 50, no se le permite retirar
             2. Se debe verificar además si la cantidad solicitada
                no es mayor a la cantidad disponible
         */
     
     private boolean hasFunds(Double cantidad){
         boolean hasFunds=false;
         if(saldo > 50 && saldo > cantidad) {
             hasFunds=true;
         }else{
             showFailInfo(cantidad);
         }
         return hasFunds;
     }      
     
     /*
         Estos son métodos informativos ...
         que puedes usar desde ingreso() o retiro() 
         o desde las verificaciones, según el caso
         */
     private void showLimitInfo(){
         System.out.printf("\n[AVISO] *Has agotado los movimientos por hoy. %d movimientos hechos",dailyLimit);
     }
     
     private void showIllegalInfo(){
         System.out.println("\n[AVISO] *Se notificará a hacienda.");
     }
    
     private void showSuccessInfo(int type, Double cantidad){
         String typeDescription= (type==1) ? "ingreso" : "retiro";
         System.out.printf("\n[AVISO] %d.\tHa ocurrido un %s de %s\tSaldo: %.2f",countIndex,typeDescription,cantidad,this.saldo);
     }
     
     private void showFailInfo(Double cantidad){
         System.out.printf("\n[AVISO] *No puedes retirar %.2f\tSaldo: %.2f",cantidad,this.saldo);
     }     
     
 }
```

---

#### Demo: <kbd>[VER EN REXTESTER](https://rextester.com/NSH72425)</kbd>

Y un demo desde el `main`:

```
    CuentaBancaria cb=new CuentaBancaria();
    cb.ingreso(100.00);
    cb.ingreso(200.00);
    cb.ingreso(500.00);
    cb.ingreso(100.00);
    cb.retiro(200.00);
    
    cb.ingreso(50000000.00);        
    cb.retiro(50000000.00); 
    cb.retiro(2999.00);       
    
    cb.retiro(400.00);
    cb.ingreso(100.00);
    cb.retiro(200.00);
    cb.ingreso(500.00);
    cb.ingreso(900.00);
    cb.retiro(29990.00);
    cb.ingreso(300.00);

    cb.movimientos();
```

**Salida:**

```
[AVISO] 1.  Ha ocurrido un ingreso de 100.0 Saldo: 100.00
[AVISO] 2.  Ha ocurrido un ingreso de 200.0 Saldo: 300.00
[AVISO] 3.  Ha ocurrido un ingreso de 500.0 Saldo: 800.00
[AVISO] 4.  Ha ocurrido un ingreso de 100.0 Saldo: 900.00
[AVISO] 5.  Ha ocurrido un retiro de 200.0  Saldo: 700.00
[AVISO] *Se notificará a hacienda.

[AVISO] *Se notificará a hacienda.

[AVISO] *No puedes retirar 2999.00  Saldo: 700.00
[AVISO] 6.  Ha ocurrido un retiro de 400.0  Saldo: 300.00
[AVISO] 7.  Ha ocurrido un ingreso de 100.0 Saldo: 400.00
[AVISO] 8.  Ha ocurrido un retiro de 200.0  Saldo: 200.00
[AVISO] 9.  Ha ocurrido un ingreso de 500.0 Saldo: 700.00
[AVISO] 10. Ha ocurrido un ingreso de 900.0 Saldo: 1600.00
[AVISO] *Se notificará a hacienda.

[AVISO] *Has agotado los movimientos por hoy. 10 movimientos hechos

MOVIMIENTOS:

100.0
200.0
500.0
100.0
200.0
400.0
100.0
200.0
500.0
900.0
```

---

#### Post-Data

En tu clase no estás respetando la *convención de nombre* propia de Java. Aunque esto no es obligatorio, ni provoca errores en el código, convendría conocerla y ponerla en práctica. Para más detalles puedes ver la pregunta: *[¿Cuál es la convención para escribir variables en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/78420/29967)*.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aportación me has ayudado bastante, respecto a lo de la retirada que mencionas... No me había dado cuenta!!! De todas formas, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo mediante un contador que llamaremos *posicionMovimiento*.

Cada vez que se ejecute el método *ingreso()* o *retirada()* sumarás +1 a la posición:

```
posicionMovimiento++;
```

Para guardar el importe del movimiento usaremos posicionMovimiento para indicar en que posición del vector lo debemos guardar:

```
movimiento[posicionMovimiento]=cantidad;
```

Quedando así:

```
public void ingreso(Double cantidad) {

    if (cantidad > 3000.00) {
        System.out.println("\n[AVISO] Se notificará a hacienda");
    }
    
    else if (posicionMovimiento==10) {

        System.out.println("No se pueden guardar más movimientos (Max 10)");
    
    } else {
        System.out.println("Ha ingresado " + cantidad + " Euros.");

    // ingresar la cantidad en el vector
    movimiento[posicionMovimiento]=cantidad;
    
    // Actualizar saldo
    saldo =+ cantidad;
    
    // Actualizar proxima posicion en el vector
    posicionMovimiento++;
    }
}
```