# ¿Como solucionar estos errores al trasladar datos entre clases (POO)?

Tags: java, poo, funciones

"Es mi primer ejercicio de POO".

El caso es que cuando intento pasar datos desde la opción 1 y 2 del Switch a la clase oficina me da error, primero intente pasar los datos del usuario al constructor oficina y luego directamente al metodo no se como hacerlo.

String oficina.oficina.getNombre()
method getNombre in class oficina.oficina cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found:    java.lang.String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length(compiler.err.cant.apply.symbol)
The method getNombre() in the type oficina is not applicable for the arguments (String)Java(67108979

```
// Importamos los paquetes necesarios para hacer funcionar la clase.
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;
import oficina.oficina;
//import oficina.puesto;

// Clase principal del programa porque contiene el procedimiento principal.
public class coworking {

    // Procedimiento principal del programa por donde empieza a ejecutarse el código.
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Creamos un objeto de la clase Scanner que nos permita reconocer los datos del teclado.
        Scanner datos = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Creamos un objeto de la clase oficina para usar sus metodos y procedimientos.
        oficina uno = new oficina();

        // Almacena datos que el usuario introduzca y los traspasa a las clases correspondientes.
        String elemento = "";
        
        // Según la opción del menú almacenada en esta variable se ejecutará un método.
        int opcionMenu = 0;

        // Se ejecuta el código hasta que el usuario desee salir del programa con la opción 9.
        while (opcionMenu != 9) {

            //  Desplegamos las opciones disponibles.
            do {
                System.out.println("—(•·÷{ Menú de opciones }÷·•)—");
                System.out.println("    1. Asignar nombre a la oficina.");
                System.out.println("    2. Asignar dirección a la oficina.");
                System.out.println("    3. Obtener nombre de la oficina.");
                System.out.println("    4. Obtener dirección de la oficina.");
                System.out.println("    5. Obtener número de puestos libres de la oficina.");
                System.out.println("    6. Asignar un puesto libre a una persona.");
                System.out.println("    7. Liberar el puesto que estaba usando una persona.");
                System.out.println("    8. Consultar quien ocupa un puesto de la oficina.");
                System.out.println("    9. Salir.");

                /*
                ** - Almacenamos la opción elegida en la siguiente variable.
                ** - Si obtiene el valor 9 el bucle while dejara de ejecutar instrucciones.
                */
                System.out.print("    ➞  "); opcionMenu = datos.nextInt();
            
            // Si la opción elegida está fuera del rango repetir la decisión.
            } while (opcionMenu < 1 || opcionMenu > 9);

            // Salto de línea estético.
            System.out.println();

            // Según la opción del menú elegida ejecutamos un método.
            switch (opcionMenu) {
                case 1:
                    // Limpiamos el buffer porque hay colisión en este punto de tipo entero y carácter.
                    datos.nextLine();
                    
                    // Recogemos datos.
                    System.out.println("Introduzca un nombre para la oficina:");
                    elemento = datos.nextLine();
                    uno.getNombre(elemento);

                    // Trasladamos datos al atributo de la clase correspondiente.
                    uno.setNombre(elemento);
                    
                    // Salto de línea estético.
                    System.out.println();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // Limpiamos el buffer porque hay colisión en este punto de tipo entero y carácter.
                    datos.nextLine();

                    // Recogemos datos.
                    System.out.println("Introduzca la dirección de la oficina:");
                    elemento = datos.nextLine();

                    // Trasladamos datos al atributo de la clase correspondiente.
                    uno.setDireccion(elemento);

                    // Salto de línea estético.
                    System.out.println();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    // Limpiamos el buffer porque hay colisión en este punto de tipo entero y carácter.
                    datos.nextLine();

                    // Llamamos al atributo e imprimimos su valor.
                    System.out.println(uno.getNombre()); 
                    
                    // Salto de línea estético.
                    System.out.println();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    // Limpiamos el buffer porque hay colisión en este punto de tipo entero y carácter.
                    datos.nextLine();

                    // Llamamos al atributo e imprimimos su valor.
                    System.out.println(uno.getDireccion());

                    // Salto de línea estético.
                    System.out.println();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    break;
                case 6:
                    break;
                case 7:
                    break;
                case 8:
                    break;
                
                // En caso de error inesperado, imprimir el siguiente mensaje.
                default:
                    System.out.println("¡UPS! ha ocurrido un error inesperado, inténtelo de nuevo.");
                    break;

            }
        }

        // Vaciamos el buffer antes de realizar una nueva ejecución de instrucciones.
        datos.nextLine();

        // Cerramos el objeto de la clase Scanner que hemos creado.
        datos.close();

    }
}

// Referencia que esta clase será perteneciente al paquete (carpeta) oficina.
package oficina;

// Importamos los paquetes necesarios para hacer funcionar la clase.
//import oficina.puesto;

// Clase que contiene el código perteneciente a las oficinas.
public class oficina {

    // Constructor de la clase.
    public oficina(){};

    /*
    ** - Atributos privados del objeto oficina.
    ** - Los métodos de acceso a los campos/atributos privados será mediante Setters y Getters.
    */
    private String nombre;
    private String direccion;

    // Matriz de tipo objeto oficina.
    puesto [][] matriz = new puesto [2][2];

    // Rellenamos la matriz con valores de datos iniciales.

    // Inicializamos la clase oficina con los atributos nombre y dirección.
    public oficina (String nombre, String direccion){
        this.setNombre(nombre);
        this.setDireccion(direccion);
    }

    //
    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    //
    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    //
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    //
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Observa la signatura de tu método `getNombre()` en la clase:

```
public String getNombre() {
```

El método **no recibe ningún parámetro**, por tanto, hacer esta llamada es incorrecto:

```
uno.getNombre(elemento);
```

porque le pasas un parámetro a un método en cuya signatura no has declarado que deba recibir parámetros. La llamada debe escribirse así (como de hecho haces en otras partes de tu código):

```
uno.getNombre();
```

Además, tienes la lógica al revés en ese punto, porque intentas obtener el nombre sin haberlo seteado:

```
                uno.getNombre(elemento);

                // Trasladamos datos al atributo de la clase correspondiente.
                uno.setNombre(elemento);
```

Debería ser al revés, en caso de necesitar realmente el nombre: primero setearlo (`setNombre()`), y luego obtenerlo (`getNombre()`):

```
                // Trasladamos datos al atributo de la clase correspondiente.
                uno.setNombre(elemento);

                // Pero ¿realmente necesitas obtener el nombre aquí?
                // Realmente esta línea en el case 1 no tiene sentido
                // uno.getNombre();
```

#### Post-Data

Te aconsejo que respetes la *convención de nombre* en Java. Los nombres de clase deben escribirse en PascalCase. Para más detalles consulta la pregunta: ***[¿Cuál es la convención para escribir variables en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/78420/29967)***