# No encuentra mi metodo GET()

Tags: android, recyclerview, get

Cuento con el siguiente codigo para llenar un recyclerview con los datos de mysql, pero al declarar la imagen me muestra la siguiente alerta **No candidates found for method call listaUsuarios.getImagen().** pero el metodo si esta declarado en mi clase usuario de donde se mandan a llamar los metodos.

El problema es que en la clase usuario el metodo se pone como desabilitado a comparacion de los otros anexo fotografia de referencia si me pudieran ayudar lo agradeceria

Ya intente declarandolo de nuevo incluso cambiando el nombre pero nada y sinceramente no se a que se deba si todo esta declarado correctamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este error es el que me muestra en problemas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Clase Adaptador

```
@Override
    public UsuarioViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_rv_usuario, viewGroup, false);
        return new UsuarioViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsuarioViewHolder usuarioViewHolder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int i) {
        usuarioViewHolder.tvIdUsuario.setText(listaUsuarios.get(i).getIdUsuario());
        usuarioViewHolder.tvNombre.setText(listaUsuarios.get(i).getNombre());
        usuarioViewHolder.tvTelefono.setText(listaUsuarios.get(i).getDepartamento());
        Glide.with(usuarioViewHolder.img.getContext()).load("http://172.30.99.143/android_db_pool2/images/"+listaUsuarios.getImagen()).into(usuarioViewHolder.img);

        usuarioViewHolder.cvTarjeta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetallesUsuario.class);
                intent.putExtra("usuario", listaUsuarios.get(i));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

```
package com.xcheko51x.buscadorrecyclerviewmysql;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    String codigo_persona;
    String Nombre;
    String Puesto;
    String Departamento;
    String Img;


    public Usuario(String codigo_persona,  String Imagen, String Nombre, String Puesto, String Departamento) {
        this.codigo_persona = codigo_persona;
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
        this.Puesto = Puesto;
        this.Departamento = Departamento;
        this.Img = Imagen;
    }

    public String getIdUsuario() {
        return codigo_persona;
    }

    public void setIdUsuario(String codigo_persona) {
        this.codigo_persona = codigo_persona;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String Nombre) {

        this.Nombre = Nombre;
    }

    public String getPuesto() {

        return Puesto;
    }

    public void setPuesto(String Puesto) {

        this.Puesto = Puesto;
    }

    public String getDepartamento() {

        return Departamento;
    }

    public void setDepartamento(String Departamento) {

        this.Departamento = Departamento;
    }

    public String getImagen() {

        return Img;
    }

    public void setImagen(String Imagen) {

        this.Img = Imagen;
    }
```

Comment: Puede que te falte este `import` al inicio de la clase: **`import java.io.Serializable;`** No veo otro motivo por el que tu clase puede ser errónea, aunque tu [*convención de nombre*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78423/29967) hace daño a los ojos, pero eso no es motivo de error, pero sí de confusión. Si tienes ese `import` y no funciona, entonces dinos qué error menciona el IDE en el apartado `Problems` y agrega todo tu código, incluyendo los `import` al principio, pulsando en [edit].

Comment: El import si lo tengo y aun asi me marca el error de que el metodo is never used ya edite el codigo y  anexe la imagen de los errores del IDE

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema ahora? Lo de *never used* es un Warning (advertencia) no un error que impida que el código compile y funcione (los errores se marcan siempre en color rojo), aunque, para una aplicación final deberías quitar todo aquello que no uses, claro está.

Comment: Si exacto el problema sigue siendo el mismo **No candidates found for method call listaUsuarios.getImagen()** ya agregue de igual manera la imagen del error que me muestra en mi clase adaptador al llamar el getimagen

Comment: `listaUsuarios` sería una lista de objetos del tipo `Usuario`, no puedes acceder directamente haciendo esto: `listaUsuarios.getImagen()` debes indicar el índice, como haces con los otros *getter*, algo así: **`listaUsuarios.get(i).getImagen()`** tienes que hacerlo parecido a como lo tienes en los `setText` observa que allí usas `get(i)`

Comment: Por si te confundes, la línea entera debería quedar así: **`Glide.with(usuarioViewHolder.img.getContext()).load("http://172.30.99.143/android_db_pool2/images/"+listaUsuarios.get(i).getImagen()).into(usuarioViewHolder.img);`**

Comment: Gracias ya no me marco el error pero no me carga la imagen empezare a revisar donde tengo la falla gracias