# Como referirte a una variable de una clase heredada para una funcion?

Tags: java, poo

Quiero utilizar la variable direccion heredada de la clase Construcciones , pero no sabria como.
Aclaracion: El IDE me genero automaticamente el Override del metodo sobre las clases que heredan de Construcciones.

```
public class Edificios extends Construcciones{
    public Edificios(double superficiePorM2, String direccion, double precioPorM2) {
        super(superficiePorM2, direccion, precioPorM2);
    }

    @Override
    public void mostrarDireccion() {
        System.out.println("La direccion de la casa es "  );
    }
```

Codigo de clase padre Construcciones de la cual hereda Edificios

```
public abstract class Construcciones implements mostrarAtributo {

    private double superficiePorM2;
    private String direccion;
    private double precioPorM2;

    public Construcciones(double superficiePorM2,String direccion,double precioPorM2){
        this.superficiePorM2 = superficiePorM2;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.precioPorM2 = precioPorM2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Subí el fuente de la clase `Construcciones` así vemos cómo está definida dirección.

Comment: No tiene sentido que sobre-escribas `mostrarDireccion()` ahí, simplemente usa el método de la clase hija y punto. Si necesitas un campo en una clase, significa entonces que ese campo pertenece a esa clase. Realmente, es contradictorio lo que intentas aquí.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tiene sentido lo que intentas hacer aquí. Simplemente coloca el método `mostrarDireccion()` en la clase padre. A no ser que quieras hacer un tratamiento especial en la clase hija, no parece ser el caso.

Algo así:

### `Construccion`

```
public abstract class Construcciones implements mostrarAtributo {

    private double superficiePorM2;
    private String direccion;
    private double precioPorM2;

    public Construcciones(double superficiePorM2,String direccion,double precioPorM2){
        this.superficiePorM2 = superficiePorM2;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.precioPorM2 = precioPorM2;
    }

    public void mostrarDireccion() {
        System.out.printf("La direccion de la casa es: %s",direccion);
    }

}
```

### `Edificio`

```
public class Edificios extends Construcciones{

    public Edificios(double superficiePorM2, String direccion, double precioPorM2) {
        super(superficiePorM2, direccion, precioPorM2);
    }

}
```

Si haces esta prueba:

```
Edificios unEdificio=new Edificios(200.1,"Calle A, no. 8",400.99);
unEdificio.mostrarDireccion();
```

Verás en pantalla:

```
La direccion de la casa es Calle A, no. 8
```

**P.D.** Por [convención de nombre](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78423/29967), tus clases deben ir en sigular: **`Construccion`** y **`Edificio`**.