# estoy creando un API, cuando hago las peticiones http de get, dos de mis variables me aparecen como null lo estoy haciendo en postman las peticiones

Tags: mysql, api, postman

// parte del codigo al implimentar los valores que necesito[image: imagen sobre el resultado ala peticion get en postman]

```
public class Candidate {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long candidateId;
    private String Candidate;
    private String Department;
    private String municipality;
    @Column(name = "num_table",unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int num_table;
    private int num_votes;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[adjunto foto de la peticion y como me aparece en mi base de datos](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1a5zgmn4G0vq61Ah2o0jy58VUsqIilxaX?usp=sharing)

Comment: En algunos entornos, si no usas camelCase para declarar las propiedades los datos no son mapeados. Prueba a declarar las propiedades que te están dando problemas así: `private String candidate;` y `private String department;` Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78423/29967) para ver más detalles sobre la convención de nombre en Java.

Comment: muchas gracias, ya lo pude solucionar, modifique las propiedades de lo que sugeristes y si me funciono .. Saludos..

Answer (score 0):

En algunos entornos, si no usas *camelCase* para declarar las propiedades los datos no son mapeados.

Prueba a declarar las propiedades que te están dando problemas así:

```
private String candidate; 
private String department;
```

Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78423/29967) para ver más detalles sobre la convención de nombre en Java. Convendría que observes lo allí mencionado para nombrar tus elementos, por claridad en el código y para evitar problemas como el actual.